# Different command definitions with and without optional argument

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I want to define a command that expands to two completely different things depending on whether I supply, or not, an optional argument. For example,

```
\mycmd{normal}            ->  something(normal)
\mycmd[optional]{normal}  ->  anotherthing(normal, optional)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See also: [latex optional arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812214/latex-optional-arguments) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Related Questions: [New command with optional argument being first argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60893/new-command-with-optional-argument-being-first-argument?rq=1), and [Different macro behavior when supplied an argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80251/different-macro-behavior-when-supplied-an-argument).

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you read deep in the LaTeX code you can find lots of examples where this is done.  Any command that has optional arguments actually does this already: there are actually two different commands and which one is called depends on whether or not it is called with an optional command.  The TeX trick is to use `\@ifnextchar[`.  For example,

```
\def\mycmd{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{hello #1, have you met #2?}
\def\@without#1{goodbye #1}
```

What happens there is that the TeX interpreter meets the `\mycmd` macro and expands it (swallowing following white-space, of course).  The first thing it then encounters is a test on the next character (which, incidentally, is non-destructive - the next character is simply observed, not processed).  If it is a square bracket, then it puts `\@with` in the stream and starts again.  `\@with` is defined to take two arguments, the first of which is surrounded by square brackets.  It therefore matches the first optional argument and the next thingy in the TeX stream.  If the next character wasn't a square bracket then `\@without` is put into the stream.  This takes one (normal) parameter.  But since `\@with` and `\@without` are two completely separate commands, they can do whatever they like with the input.

(Note: For commands defined with `\newcommand` which take an optional parameter then sort-of what happens is that the two commands `\@with` and `\@without` expand to the same command, but the optional parameter of `\@with` gets passed to it as the first parameter whereas in `\@without` the default value is passed.  It's not *quite* like that, but the difference is more in conciseness of programming than anything else.)

Here's a fully compilable example, including the mysterious and mystical duo [`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/86):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314/86}

\makeatletter
\def\mycmd{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{Hello #1, have you met #2?}
\def\@without#1{Goodbye #1.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mycmd[Polyphemus]{Odysseus}
\mycmd{Circe}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

> Hello Polyphemus, have you met Odysseus?  Goodbye Circe.

Comment: This solution is very nice and clean, thanks!

Comment: @juan: but it uses `\def` instead of `\newcommand` which isn’t recommended in LaTeX. To note just one advantage, `\newcommand` tests whether the command already exists and provides meaningful diagnostics, while `\def` will just override the command, potentially breaking other code. So, in summary, don’t use `\def` when `\newcommand` will do.

Comment: @Konrad: absolutely!  _Never_ use raw TeX unless you know what you are doing!  But surrounding the whole thing in an `\@ifundefined` would satisfy your requirement, I deem.

Comment: Yup, I know the difference on when and when not to use each. I'm a bit of a TeX-hacker myself ;-) Also thanks for your LaTeX-friendlier solutions!

Comment: Perhaps worth saying that - for the archive - I wouldn't feel happy if this were the _only_ solution posted, but as Konrad had already given a LaTeX solution, I felt happy posting a TeX one.

Comment: I have a question, namely does your last sentence mean that this will not work with \newcommand? Also, if want an undefined number of optional arguments, can I iterate the definition in some way?

Comment: @NickKidman Sorry, didn't see your comment originally.  I don't see why this wouldn't work with iterations - keep testing the stream to see if the next character is `[`.  But I suspect that there are better ways of doing that.

Comment: A weakness of this solution is that `\mycmd` will be fragile, so it should be preceded by `\protect` when used in moving arguments.

Comment: Why does the square bracket in ``\@ifnextchar[`` have no closing square bracket?

Comment: @user69453 In this case the `[` is not part of a pair of brackets enclosing an argument.  The `\@ifnextchar[` looks at the next character in the stream and tests to see if it is `[` to see if there is an optional argument or not.  Thus in this case `[` is playing the role of just a simple single character.

Comment: One downside is that you cannot use this to create more commands without renaming the `with` and `without`.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Of course, this is a demonstration of how it can be done, not a template for a general system.  There would be ways of adapting this so that the auxiliary commands have a systematic naming scheme, but it would depend on how you specified the two separate actions.  But that's a different question.  Anyway, nowadays, I'd probably just use `xparse` with a few conditionals.

Answer (score 71):

The LaTeX3 xparse package is designed to aid the construction of macros that take complex optional arguments. In this case, you'd write

```
\usepackage{xparse}
....
\DeclareDocumentCommand \foo { o m } {%
  \IfNoValueTF {#1} {%
    \something {#2}%
  }{%
    \someotherthing {#1} {#2}%
  }%
}
```

Internally, this does the same thing as Andrew's answer, but the coding is a little more straightforward/readable and it is also more easily extended. Want another optional argument? Just add another `o` in the `{ o m }` argument. (`o` is ‘optional argument’ and `m` is ‘mandatory argument’; see the xparse documentation for more.)

Comment: Does \IfNoValue check if the second argument was supplied or does it check if the first argument was empty. That is does it distinguish between \foo[something] and \foo[][something] and what if I want the opposite behaviour?

Comment: It checks if the first argument was not supplied. It is also possible to specify a default with O{default} which I think might be what you're thinking of. There isn't an \IfEmpty conditional in xparse but there is an equivalent in expl3 or ifmtarg.

Comment: Better use `\IfNoValueTF {#1} {%`. If the optional argument takes more then one digit, this will be important.

Comment: Note that foo is then used as `\foo{One argument}`, `\foo[First argument]{Second argument}`, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 57):

I want to thank for all of the other answers received. But lately I've turned into a huge fan of the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package, which provides a great abstraction to do exactly what I wanted at the LaTeX level (with no low level TeX trickery):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\mycmd[2][]{%
  \ifstrempty{#1}{%
    % something with #2
  }{%
    % some other thing with #1 and #2
  }%
}
```

Answer (score 26):

I'd prefer Will Robertson's solution, that's more manageable. For a "pure" LaTeX solution:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ifemptyarg#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % H. Oberdiek
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mycmd}[1][]{%
   \ifemptyarg{#1}
     {<code for empty argument>}
     {<code for non empty argument>}%
}
```

Comment: For some reason calling `\mycmd` in both cases leaves the mandatory argument in the stream, i.e. `\mycmd{a}` generates `<code for non empty argument>a`

Comment: @ScumCoder `\mycmd` has *no* mandatory argument.

Comment: Oh... I see. So the usage is either `\mycmd`, or `\mycmd[a]`.

Answer (score 13):

I usually just use the `ifthen` package to solve this, by testing whether the optional argument is empty.

```
\newcommand\mycmd@noargs{foo}
\newcommand\mycmd@withargs[1]{bar #1}
\newcommand\mycmd[1][]{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{
    \mycmd@noargs{}}{
    \mycmd@withargs{#1}}}
```

(Notice that since it uses `@` as a letter, you need to use `\makeatletter` before this definition if it’s in your main LaTeX file (instead of a package), and `\makeatother` after it.)

Comment: This is not really a solution, I'm afraid: test it with `\mycmd[aa]` where `\ifx` returns true because it compares `a` with `a`.

Comment: @egreg Whoa. Surprising that nobody has noticed this for two years.

Comment: (Note that egreg and Konrad are discussing a pure-Tex alternative that has now been edited out.)