# What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?

Tags: macros, catcodes

Many LaTeX “hacks” begin with `\makeatletter` and end with `\makeatother`. What do these commands do?

Comment: As for a reference, http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tugindia/2002-January/000178.html

Comment: For the absolute beginners; the commands should be read as **Make @ symbol a letter** and **Make @ symbol an "other"**.It's NOT *Make when you encounter a letter* and *Make when you encounter others*.

Comment: @percusse Hah. I've been compiling things in LaTeX since 2005 and I didn't know that.

Comment: How bizarre and obscure.  I love what LaTeX does, but the more I learn it, the more I realize what a crazy hack it is.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11750/how-bad-is-slack-makeatother-discipline-really

Comment: hellish language. why do people say it's easy

Comment: @percusse lol, that's the clearest answer, I got it as soon as I read this.

Comment: @ChristianChapman, Who's been saying it's easy??

Comment: Related question: [macros - Why doesn't \makeatletter work inside \newcommand? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201348/why-doesnt-makeatletter-work-inside-newcommand)

Answer (score 905, accepted):

All characters in TeX are assigned a [Category Code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode) or "catcode". There are 16 catcodes in all, some containing just a single character, e.g. `\` is (normally) catcode 0, `{`, catcode 1 etc. Normal characters are catcode 11; this category normally comprises all of the letter characters.  The `@` symbol is given the catcode of 12, which means it is *not* treated as a normal letter.  The effects of this are that `@` cannot normally be used in user document files as part of a multicharacter macro name. (All other non-letter characters are also forbidden in macro names: for example, `\foo123`, and `\foo?!` are not valid macro names.)

In LaTeX class and package files, however, `@` is treated as a normal letter (catcode 11) and this allows package writers to make macro-names with `@`.  The advantage of this is that such macro names are automatically protected from regular users: since they cannot use `@` as a normal letter, there is no accidental way for a user to override or change a macro that is part of the internal workings of a package.

However, it is sometimes necessary in user documents to *have* access to such package-internal macros, and so the commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` change the catcode of `@` from 12 to 11 and 11 to 12, respectively.

In practical terms, if you need to modify a package internal macro that contains the `@` symbol in its name, you will need to surround your modifications by these commands:

```
\makeatletter % changes the catcode of @ to 11
<your changes here>
\makeatother % changes the catcode of @ back to 12
```

The commands should not be used within `.sty` and `.cls` files themselves as they may conflict with the catcode changes that occurs when package and class files are loaded. For more information on this see [Is it really bad to use \makeatletter and \makeatother in a package or class file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62583/2693).

Comment: Good explanation. Just one minor point: You can use `@` in normal text, you just can't use it as part of a macro name.

Comment: @Caramdir: Not quite true. `\@` is a perfectly good macro. It's what Knuth calls a control symbol. If the category code of @ is 11, then `\@` becomes a control word.

Comment: @TH. is is okay to say „can't use it as part of a multi-letter macro name”?

Comment: @TH @Caramdir: Right.  I'll fix that in the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Alan: The category numbers 0 to 15 result in 16 (!) catcodes. The TeXbook (p. 37) confirms this. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: Damn computer scientists starting everything at 0. :-).  Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: The TeXnical term for "multiletter macro name" is "control word."

Comment: @Philipp: Given the audience for this question, surely multiletter macro name is a much more understandable term.

Comment: @Alan: We [computer scientists] do like to confuse things. =) In a sense, there are actually 17 catcodes. It's really not relevant for this question, but in the context of `\ifcat`, control sequences (which includes control words, control symbols, and control spaces) have category code 16. See _TeX by Topic_, Section 13.2.2.

Comment: @Alan: +1. Maybe give an explicit example like \@title? Per http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tugindia/2002-January/000178.html. To summarize, a normal user is not supposed to do \@title but a package author is allowed, so to speak, and \makeatletter makes \@title 'legal'.

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation. The way the command is phrased, I thought it was telling the compiler to make something execute at a specific letter. It's literally: "make the "at" symbol a letter. It's actually pretty funny.

Comment: Are there other possible catcode changes?

Comment: @MickG In principle, the catcode of anything can be changed, but in practice, it's generally going to cause trouble unless you really know what you're doing. It's sometimes useful to change catcodes within an environment but again, without a good amount of knowledge of how TeX works, it's not recommended.

Comment: So I could do `\makebackslashletter`, right? And how would I get back? Just for curiosity :).

Comment: @MickG No, there is no general command `\make<foo>letter`.  The `\makeatletter` commands are one off.

Comment: So it's like `sudo`?

Package writers have set things up such that users can't *accidentally* break things, but if you know that you really do want to do something (*i.e.* you really *do* need to change a macro that's internal to the workings of a package) then there's a way to say [obey me](http://blogs.ca.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/root.png)?

Comment: @owjburnham Well at a very broad level yes, but in reality not really. The @ commands are merely a reserved namespace. At best it's security by obscurity.

Comment: There is a typo "cannnot", but I can't change this, because edits must be at least 6 characters. Can any administrator change this?

Comment: Gosh. All this time, I thought that `\makeatletter` makes a tletter, and `\makeatother` makes a tother. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn Should `@` usages in `\@ne`, `\tw@`, `\sixt@@n`, `\m@ne`, `\insc@unt` or `\e@ch@ck` be considered as indicators of “reserved namespace” :-D  Certainly, the exception does prove the rule!

Comment: @ryolait I don't see why not. These are used in the LaTeX kernel and it makes sense that they are reserved.

Comment: @AlanMunn  , so could we use \@title without \makeatletter ? I understood, we use the \makeatletter just when the macro be \title@title, is that true?

Comment: @مأمونعماد No. Any macro containing @ anywhere in its name cannot be used in a user document unless you use `\makeatletter`. Since these commands are intended to be  internal commands you shouldn’t change them unless you know what you are doing.