# Optional argument for newcommand?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument)

I would like to define a macro which takes an optional argument, and behaves in different ways depending on if the optional argument is given or not. As a very simple example, I would like to define a new macro

`\newcommand{\example}[0][]{`*`macro definition`*`}`

which outputs

`optional argument was omitted`

if the optional argument was omitted, and

`optional argument was given`

if the optional argument was given. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note that `[0]` here would create a command with no arguments at all: you need `[1][]` to have one optional argument.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\test}[1][]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{omitted}{given}%
}

\begin{document}

The optional argument was \test[].

The optional argument was \test[shubidu].

\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image]

Comment: Slightly better: `\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}` (the `\isempty` test is provided by `xifthen`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it existed. You live and learn!

Comment: Also, it seems `\ifx` can be used: `\newcommand{\test}[1][]{ \def\tst{#1} \ifx\tst\empty \typeout{optional argument was omitted} \else \typeout{optional argument was given: '#1'} \fi }`

Comment: @TomBombadil Is there a way to make `\test` accept its argumets with `{}` rather than with `[]`?

Comment: @yohbs: Yes, but then it would not be an _optional_ argument anymore: `\newcommand{\test}[1]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}{}}{omitted}{given}}`

Comment: @TomBombadil why does it stop working as an optional argument if you want to use `{}`? It is just because the `{}` works as a grouping here, and not as the "parenthesis" for a command or something? Essentially: with the code you wrote above, why does it fail to work as expected when I write `\test{testarg}`?

Comment: Additionally, when I make the argument non-optional, why does `\test[testarg]` not work as expected (it seems not actually pass any argument).

Comment: I am trying to define a command as such:
`\newcommand{\gesetze}[2]{http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/#1/\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{__#2.html}}`

The idea is that, if an optional second argument is given, it appends `__#2.html` to the url, and if not, it ends after `#1/`. However, this gives an error.