# Make a \newcommand argument optional without consequence

Tags: spacing, optional-arguments, ifthenelse

I have this code block in my .cls file -

```
\newcommand{\ExperienceEntry}[5]{
    \noindent\makebox[\width][l]{#1} \hfill
    \makebox[\width][l]{#2} \\
    \noindent\makebox[\width][l]{#3} \hfill \\
    \indent
    \makebox[\width][l]{\textit{#4}} \vspace{5pt}\\
    \noindent
    \parbox[t][\height][c]{\textwidth}{\small{#5}}
    \vspace{-1pt}
}
```

How do I make the 3rd argument (`#3`) optional? By optional I mean if I leave it empty `{}`, I do not want a gaping space in my document.

For example this is what happens:
This is the .tex code -
[image]
and this is the generated document -
[image: Example of gaping space]

I found some relevant documentation about different behaviour depending on the arguments supplied -
[Different command definitions with and without optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument)
[Optional argument for newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58628/optional-argument-for-newcommand)
but i wasn't sure how to use it in my case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812214/latex-optional-arguments seems most relevant but here one has to define a default behavior whereas I want the default behavior to be to ignore the argument.

Comment: I see no gap if I leave empty `#2`. By the way, `\makebox[\width][l]{abc}` is a complicated way to say `\mbox{abc}`.

Comment: Thanks for the `\mbox` tip! I edited the question to show an example of the generated gap.

Comment: also why all the `\noindent` that does nothing mid paragraph. Note it is confusing to call this an optional parameter as latex optional parameters are marked with `[]` not `{}` and can be omitted entirely not by using an empty argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an "optional argument" in LaTeX terminology, they use `[]` not `{}`. However you can test for the argument being non empty in several ways, for example

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
  \mbox{#2}\\ 
\fi
```

if `#2` is empty this ends up testing `\if\relax\relax`  which is true, in any other case the test will be false, and so `#2` will be used. (Note I simplified `\makebox` to `\mbox` and removed the spurious space before `\\`)

---

It looks like you meant to test `#3` not `#2`..

Note

```
  \noindent\makebox[\width][l]{#3} \hfill \\
```

you do not need `\hfill` before `\\` and you should not have a space before `\hfill` and as noted previously you can simply use `\mbox`, so you can replace this line by

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else
  \mbox{#3}\\ 
\fi
```

Comment: I think I am making some mistake combining your code around `{#1}` with my existing code around it. 
This is what I am getting - 
`\noindent\mbox{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else{#1}} \hfill   
    \mbox{#2}\\  
    fi`
Which does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PratyushDas sorry the description was correct but I had a `#1` instead of `#2`  in one place in the code. The fragment in my answer should replace your line `\makebox[\width][l]{#2} \\ ` However as egreg commented an empty `#2` will not make any gap with your code as posted I think you meant to test `#3` the example you added later had an empty _third_ argument not second.

Comment: @PratyushDas see extended answer