# Bracket position rule

Tags: syntax

What is rule in specifying bracket position:

```
\foo[]{} %or 
\foo{}[]
```

Following syntaxes are clear, is there any other combinations?

```
\foo{}{} 
\foo{} 
...
```

Comment: Assuming you are asking about parameters to macros: The first and last are the usual uses. An example of the first is `\sqrt[3]{2}`, and the `[]` represent an optional parameter.  The third is the normal case of two parameters as in `\frac{}{}`. The second, having the optional parameter following the mandatory is possible using [the `xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) but I would recommend not doing that.

Comment: there is no general rule, it depends on what the developer had in mind. Any number and any combination of parameters are possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) allows you to easily specify the type and order of the parameters supplied to an argument. In terms of optional arguments with square brackets `[]` (most common), use `o` or `O{<default>}`, while a mandatory argument is specified using `m`. So, for example,

#### `\foo[]{}`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{o m}
```

#### `\foo{}[]`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m o}
```

#### `\foo{}{}`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m m}
```

`xparse` allows any combination of the above (to a maximum of 9 arguments) and intermixed versions thereof. *This mostly depends on the application or intended uses*. For example, the [`wrapfig` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) provides the `wrapfig` environment that takes arguments of the following form (using `xparse` notation): `o m o m`.

Using more than one *consecutive* optional argument is typically avoided, since you can't specify the latter without specifying the former, making them somewhat non-optional and therefore confusing.

Producing optional arguments the "traditional" way is achieved via "helper macros" - additional macros that are executed depending on the type of argument(s) supplied. This allows for the argument between `[]` to be considered optional:

```
\def\mycmd{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{hello #1, have you met #2?}
\def\@without#1{goodbye #1}
```

The above shorthand followed from [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308/5764).

Comment: With `xparse` you can get away with multiple optionals and avoid some confusion using different delimiters, e.g. `\NewDocumentCommand {\foo} { d<> d() d[] }`

Comment: @ScottH. You could but you shouldn't use delimiters just to distinguish arguments. LaTeX always uses `[]` for optional arguments except in special cases `()` for picture mode coordinates  and `<>` for package-specific syntax such as beamer.  If you ned a lot of options it is better to use a single `[]` argument and then a key=value syntax within that.