# Cornell note-taking with indexing

Tags: indexing

In [Cornell Notes - A lyx or latex solution needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70570/cornell-notes-a-lyx-or-latex-solution-needed), I like Fran's Cornell note-taking template. Does anyone know how to allow indexing in the red and blue text boxes? I want to use the `\index{}` command to make an index for my notes but when I use `\index{}` in one of Fran's text boxes, the text box is empty.

Comment: Close-Voters: Give some time to improve the question

Comment: Maybe you can come up with a short [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have tried and how it didn't work for you. So we don't have to guess what you are trying to do. I just tried the example Fran posted in their answer and added a bit of standard `\index`ing stuff (`\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex`, `\printindex` as well as the odd `\index` in the boxes) and everything worked as expected.

Comment: The `\index{...}` command works for me within `\cornell{...}` --> the index is there!

Comment: Without a MWE this is just guesswork as to how you added `\index`, but a common mistake is to assume that `\index` displays its argument in addition to indexing it, whereas in fact it just indexes the argument without displaying it so if you've done `\cornell{\index{stuff}}{...}` then the text box will be empty. You need to do `\cornell{stuff\index{stuff}}{...}`

Answer (score 3):

I took the code from the linked question and added `\index{some text}` inside the `\cornell` box command. Using `\index{}` alone of course will lead to empty index entries, showing nothing!

In my opinion it's not go idea to index the whole box text, but only some key words, so I refrained from providing a wrapper command like `\textforbox{foo}` where `foo` appears both as the text inside the box and as index entry. (This would require more setup anyway, since `\index` might have an optional argument if `imakeidx` is used, and the `subentry` syntax makes it more difficult too)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\title{
\vspace{-3em}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\Huge\sffamily Cornell Notes on Something   
\end{tcolorbox}
\vspace{-3em}
}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\date{}

\usepackage{background}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{red}
\SetBgContents{\rule[0em]{4pt}{\textheight}}
\SetBgHshift{-2.3cm}
\SetBgVshift{0cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate dummy text for the example



%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314/86}

\makeatletter
\def\cornell{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2#3{
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=gray,colframe=black,fonttitle=\large\bfseries\sffamily,sidebyside=true, nobeforeafter,before=\vfil,after=\vfil,colupper=blue,sidebyside align=top, lefthand width=.3\textwidth,
opacityframe=0,opacityback=.3,opacitybacktitle=1, opacitytext=1,
segmentation style={black!55,solid,opacity=0,line width=3pt},
title=#1
]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!05,colframe=red!25,sidebyside align=top,
width=\textwidth,nobeforeafter]#2\end{tcolorbox}%
\tcblower
\sffamily
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth,nobeforeafter]
#3
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\def\@without#1#2{
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=white!15,colframe=white,fonttitle=\bfseries,sidebyside=true, nobeforeafter,before=\vfil,after=\vfil,colupper=blue,sidebyside align=top, lefthand width=.3\textwidth,
opacityframe=0,opacityback=0,opacitybacktitle=0, opacitytext=1,
segmentation style={black!55,solid,opacity=0,line width=3pt}
]

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!05,colframe=red!25,sidebyside align=top,
width=\textwidth,nobeforeafter]#1\end{tcolorbox}%
\tcblower
\sffamily
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth,nobeforeafter]
#2
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt

%\newcommand{\cornell}[2]{%
%}

%\AddEverypageHook{
%\hspace{.3\textwidth}\vrule width 3pt depth .4\textheight 
%\vspace{-\textheight}}

\providecommand{\LyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}

\makeindex

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\SetBgContents{\rule[0em]{4pt}{\textheight}}

\cornell{\index{Research question}Research question}{\lipsum*[2]}
\cornell{Another research question}{\lipsum*[5]}
\cornell[A fancy very important question]{Thi is easy to write?}{Even without \LyX{}, is not too hard fill this template, but you must compile twice.}
\cornell{Another research question very long for one line.}{\lipsum*[1]}
\cornell{\index{Fill much more}Do you want fill much more than a page}{No problem. \lipsum*[3]}
\cornell{More?}{No problem. \lipsum*[3-4]}

\cornell[Last question]{This is the end?}{Yes.}


\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]