# How to match width of `tcolorbox` box in this Cornell notes template?

Tags: tcolorbox

Working from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273223/90325), I'd like to create a template that includes a box below the title, of the same width as the title box. This would serve as a place for things like a summary of what's to come, or a series of questions to be answered in the rest of the document.

I've started to separate the code in the answer above into a `.cls` file, and I've managed to make a new command for the summary box. I can't determine how to set the width of this box so that it matches the right and left edges of the title box and the paired boxes below.

How can one align these edges?

[image]

My `cornell.cls` file:

```
\ProvidesClass{cornell}
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\date{}
\usepackage{background}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{red}
\SetBgContents{\rule[0em]{0pt}{\textheight}}
\SetBgHshift{-2.3cm}
\SetBgVshift{0cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\parindent=0pt

\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\preread{ m m }
{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white, width=\textwidth]
    #1
        \tcblower
        #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\topic{ m m g g g g g}
{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,opacityframe=0,opacityback=0,opacitybacktitle=0, opacitytext=1,lefthand width=.3\textwidth]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!05,colframe=red!25,sidebyside align=top,width=\textwidth,before skip=0pt]
        #1.\end{tcolorbox}%
        \tcblower
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth,before skip=0pt]
            #2
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \IfNoValueF {#3}{
                \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
                #3
                \end{tcolorbox}
            }
            \IfNoValueF {#4}{
                \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
                #4
                \end{tcolorbox}
            }
            \IfNoValueF {#5}{
                \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
                #5
                \end{tcolorbox}
            }
            \IfNoValueF {#6}{
                \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
                #6
                \end{tcolorbox}
            }
            \IfNoValueF {#7}{
                \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
                #7
                \end{tcolorbox}
            }
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\def\summary#1{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=south,yshift=-1ex] at (current page text area.south) {% 
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%%%%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,opacityback=0]
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colframe=black,fonttitle=\large\bfseries\sffamily,sidebyside=true, nobeforeafter,before=\vfil,after=\vfil,colupper=black,sidebyside align=top, lefthand width=.95\textwidth,opacitybacktitle=1, opacitytext=1,
%segmentation style={black!55,solid,opacity=0,line width=3pt},
title=Summary
]
#1
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

My `examplenotes.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{cornell}
\begin{document} 

\title{
    \vspace{-3em}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,opacityback=0]
            \begin{tcolorbox}
                \Huge\sffamily Cornell Notes on Something
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace{-3em}
}
\maketitle

\preread{Questions}{The questions}

\topic{Key term}%
{Definition}%
{Some other stuff about the term/concept.}%

\topic{Here's another question.}{\lipsum[1]}%
{\lipsum[2]}%

\summary{Summary for the page.}

\topic{Here's another question to begin the new page.}{\lipsum[3]}%
{\lipsum[4]}%
{\lipsum[5]}%

\summary{And another summary that will float to the bottom of the next page.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With other words: The `preread` box should have the same width like the topic box (the one with `Cornell notes on something`)?

Comment: Yes @Christian that's precisely right. I've tried fiddling with   width, but that didn't solve the left alignment. I gather there's something else I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer but an example which shows the problem. I don't know why, but all your `tcolorboxes` are declared inside other `tcolorboxes`. This encapsulation introduces changes in `\textwidth` which is different for `preread` (fixed by `geometry`) and for `topic` pair of boxes.

As you can see if `preread` is introduced into a `tcolorbox` all margins are equal. Now you must decide if all these `external` boxes are necessary or not.

```
\documentclass{cornell}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document} 

\title{
    \vspace{-3em}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,opacityback=0]
            \begin{tcolorbox}
                \Huge\sffamily Cornell Notes on Something
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace{-3em}
}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}
\preread{Questions}{The questions}
\end{tcolorbox}

\topic{Key term}%
{Definition}%
{Some other stuff about the term/concept.}%

\topic{Here's another question.}{\lipsum[1]}%
{\lipsum[2]}%

\summary{Summary for the page.}

\topic{Here's another question to begin the new page.}{\lipsum[3]}%
{\lipsum[4]}%
{\lipsum[5]}%

\summary{And another summary that will float to the bottom of the next page.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) You find the nested boxes as weird as I do ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I confess I took the nesting from the linked question without much scrutiny. It struck me as a little peculiar, but I'm too new to have known whether this is the TeX equivalent of a code smell.

Answer (score 6):

As referenced in another answer, this is due to the choice to nest `tcolorbox` boxes inside each other. The approach below avoids this using [`parcolumns`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns).

[image]

The `.cls` file:

```
\ProvidesClass{cornell}
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\date{}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\cornelltitle{ m }
{
    \vspace{-3em}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,lowerbox=invisible]
                \Huge\sffamily #1
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace{-3em}
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\preread{ m m }
{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth]
    #1
    \tcblower 
        #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\note{ o m }
{
    \begin{parcolumns}[colwidths={1=.3\textwidth},nofirstindent]{2}
        \colchunk{ 
            \IfNoValueF{#1} {
                \begin{tcolorbox}[lowerbox=invisible, box align=top]
                #1 
                \end{tcolorbox}
            }{}
        }
        \colchunk{ 
            \begin{tcolorbox}[lowerbox=invisible, box align=top]
            #2
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }
    \end{parcolumns}
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\summary{ m }
{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[floatplacement=b,float]
    Summary
    \tcblower
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

Sample `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{cornell}
\begin{document}
\title{
    \cornelltitle{A topic we're taking notes on}
}
\maketitle
\preread
    {Questions}
    {
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item{What's the first question this section will answer?}
            \item{What's the second question?}
        \end{enumerate}
    }
\note[Some key term]
{
    \begin{itemize} 
        \item{A cool thing}
        \item{Another cool thing}
        \item{Not all things are cool}
    \end{itemize}
}
\note[Another term]
{
    \lipsum[4]
}
\note{\lipsum[5]}

\summary{A fabulous summary}
\note[]{\lipsum[6]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I extended this solution and created a repository to share it: https://gitlab.com/MLNW/cornell-notes-template