# How to create command that associates pieces of content to keep them on same page?

Tags: macros

I've pieced together a class for my preferred format of [Cornell notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276410/how-to-match-width-of-tcolorbox-box-in-this-cornell-notes-template), and it allows for floating a summary to the bottom of a page. But, it requires manually choosing the page that will host the summary.

Ideally, I'd specify a command such that all the arguments are positioned on the same page, with the third argument appearing in the summary box at bottom. For example:

```
\note
 {This heading should appear to the left...}
 {...of this paragraph in the main text.}
 {This should be concatenated with other third arguments and positioned at page bottom.}
```

Put another way, it's a bit like leaving the enumeration off of footnotes, and stringing them into a paragraph.

How can one create commands that position notes at page bottom, subject to the constraint that each note shows on the same page as some other associated element?

Comment: Even footnotes aren't guaranteed to fit on the same page.  You can create a new float type using the float package.  You might need to increase \bottomfraction if you intend large notes.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo, I'll look into the float package. Long notes isn't a concern—the summary should be limited to a sentence per body paragraph at most. I'll reading [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020), thoroughly and give it a go. Thanks!