# Set tcolorbox overlay bookmark to be above its parent

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, xparse, bookmarks

I added a new environment to my [Cornell-styled notes](https://gitlab.com/MLNW/cornell-notes-template): `titlednote`

It allows adding a title to a note which should also generate a bookmark below its `term`.
But since `terms` are implemented with a `tcolorbox` overlay the bookmark of a `titlednote` that defines a `term` is not below the overlay.

Here is an example where the `Date` bookmark should be below `Meeting Context`
[image: exampe]

The `cornell.cls` for this example is as follows:

```latex
\ProvidesClass{cornell}
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary
{
    breakable,% Allows tcolorboxes to break across pages
    hooks,% Allows usage of hooks, like having an overlay only for the first part of a broken box
    skins,% Used to style the boxes with tikz
    xparse% Used to define document environments and commands
}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % Change geometry of pages
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Modify parindent and parskip
\usepackage{enumitem} % Modify itemize spacing
\setitemize
{
    itemsep=0pt,
    parsep=2pt,
}

\usepackage{bookmark} % Add bookmarks to the resulting PDF
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup
{
    colorlinks   = true, % Colour links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = blue, % Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = blue, % Colour of internal links
    citecolor    = red   % Colour of citations
}

\date{}

\tcbset
{
    colframe=black,
    colupper=black,
    opacitybacktitle=1,
    opacitytext=1,
    fonttitle=\large\bfseries\sffamily,
}

\NewTColorBox[]{titlebox}{ o }
{
    width=\textwidth,
    lowerbox=invisible,
    bookmark*={level=0}{\@title}
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{
    \vspace{-3em}
    \begin{titlebox}
        \Huge{\sffamily{\@title}}
    \end{titlebox}
}

\NewTColorBox[]{extra}{ m }
{
    width=\textwidth,
    title=#1,
    bookmark*={level=1}{#1},
}

\NewTColorBox[]{term}{ m }
{
    width=.325\textwidth,
    bookmark*={level=1}{#1},
}

\NewTColorBox[]{note}{ o }
{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    enlarge left by=.34\textwidth,
    width=.66\textwidth,
    parbox=false,% restore main text formatting behavior
    overlay unbroken={
        \IfNoValueF{#1} {%
            \node[anchor=north west, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-.34\textwidth]frame.north west) {
                \begin{term}{#1}
                    #1
                \end{term}
            };
        }{}
    },
    overlay first app={
        \IfNoValueF{#1} {%
            \node[anchor=north west, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-.34\textwidth]frame.north west) {
                \begin{term}{#1}
                    #1
                \end{term}
            };
        }{}
    }
}

\NewTColorBox[]{titlednote}{ om }
{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    title=#2,
    bookmark*={level=2}{#2},
    enlarge left by=.34\textwidth,
    width=.66\textwidth,
    parbox=false,% restore main text formatting behavior
    overlay unbroken={
        \IfNoValueF{#1} {%
            \node[anchor=north west, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-.34\textwidth]frame.north west) {
                \begin{term}{#1}
                    #1
                \end{term}
            };
        }{}
    },
    overlay first app={
        \IfNoValueF{#1} {%
            \node[anchor=north west, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-.34\textwidth]frame.north west) {
                \begin{term}{#1}
                    #1
                \end{term}
            };
        }{}
    }
}
```

And the sample that produces the screenshot is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{cornell}

\title{Some meeting notes}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{titlednote}[Meeting Context]{Date}
    Wednesday
\end{titlednote}
\begin{titlednote}{Moderator}
    Max Mustermann
\end{titlednote}
\begin{titlednote}{Participants}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
        \item C
        \item D
    \end{itemize}
\end{titlednote}

\end{document}
```

I tried to modify the `titlednode` environment by changing the `term` from an overlay to a separate `tcolorbox`.
That fixes the issue with the bookmark, but it introduces a layouting issue:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{titlednote}{ om }
{
    \IfNoValueF{#1}{
        \begin{term}{#1}
            #1
        \end{term}
    }
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            enhanced,
            breakable,
            title=#2,
            bookmark*={level=2}{#2},
            enlarge left by=.34\textwidth,
            width=.66\textwidth,
            parbox=false,% restore main text formatting behavior
        ]
}
{
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: modified solution]

I did not find a way to calculate the (dynamic) height of the `term` `tcolorbox` in order to use negative `vspace`. That would solve the issue but there must be a way to fix this issue.

Comment: How about removing `bookmark*` from `term` and put `IfValueT={#1}{bookmark*={level=1}{#1}}, bookmark*={level=2}{#2},` into `titlednote`? That should give the desired sequence (for your first code).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm that solved the issue. Thank you very much! I did not know it is possible to use functions like `IfValueT` in the options of a `tcolorbox`. Is this specific to your package or is that something that `xparse` allows?

Comment: `IFValueT` is from the `xparse` library of `tcolorbox`; of course, based on `xparse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to the issue was provided by @ThomasF.Sturm as a comment. For sake of completeness here is it applied to my question.

Instead of defining the bookmark in the overlay, define the bookmark in the parent `tcolorbox`. In order to do so one can check if the optional parameter for a term was provided or not.

```
\NewTColorBox[]{term}{ m }
{
    width=.325\textwidth,
%    bookmark*={level=1}{#1}, %<< Redundant, now set by titlednote environment
}

\NewTColorBox[]{titlednote}{ om }
{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    title=#2,
    IfValueT={#1}{bookmark*={level=1}{#1}}, %<< Set term bookmark only if it was provided
    bookmark*={level=2}{#2},
    enlarge left by=.34\textwidth,
    width=.66\textwidth,
    parbox=false,
    overlay unbroken={
        \IfNoValueF{#1} {%
            \node[anchor=north west, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-.34\textwidth]frame.north west) {
                \begin{term}{#1}
                    #1
                \end{term}
            };
        }{}
    },
    overlay first app={
        \IfNoValueF{#1} {%
            \node[anchor=north west, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-.34\textwidth]frame.north west) {
                \begin{term}{#1}
                    #1
                \end{term}
            };
        }{}
    }
}
```