# Tcolorbox, minted and listing without caption

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted

I'm trying to have a non-captionned listing using tcolorbox and minted.
I've made a macro that automates the task, with the title of the snippet as optional argument.

My goal is, when the optional argument is empty, not print a caption (nor register the listing in the list of listings).

I don't see how I can do it, since there is no possibility to add an ifcase in the tcolorbox declaration.

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most,minted]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{helloworld.java}
public class HelloWorld {
    // A 'Hello World' in Java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
\end{filecontents*}


\AtBeginDocument{
\newtcbinputlisting[blend into=listings]{\mylisting}[2][]{%
    listing engine=minted,
    listing file={#2},
    listing only,
    breakable,
    title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #1},
    list text=#1,
    label={lst:\thetcbcounter},
    detach title,
    listing above comment,
    comment=\centering\tcbtitletext,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    minted language=java,
    minted style=colorful,
    minted options={%
        tabsize=2,
        fontsize=\footnotesize,
        xleftmargin=2em,
        autogobble=true,
        numbers=left,
        numbersep=5pt,
        fontsize=\footnotesize,
        breaklines=true,
    },
    left=-2em,
    left skip=1em,
    width=\linewidth-1em,}

}

\begin{document}
    
\lstlistoflistings
    
\section{Test}

\mylisting{helloworld.java}  % This should not have a caption

\mylisting[Hello world]{helloworld.java}


\end{document}
```

How can I do it ? As you can see, the 1st listing in the MWE does have an empty caption, where it shouldn't.

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Two options. You can declare two different boxes one with title and one without and a third one where you test the title and decide to use one or another. The second solution could be to look what `blend into listingds` does and include this code in your box only when a title exists. Take a look a `xparse` library in `tcolorbox` documentation. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581947/1952) which is not related with you r question can see how conditinals provided by `xparse` library can be used.