# How to align two tcolorboxes in this template?

Tags: tcolorbox

I found this great template for Cornell styled note-taking: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273223

Sadly, when I compile this document the left and right boxes are not top-aligned:

[image: This shows the issue]

I have looked through the documentation and mucked about in the code but I cannot find the reason why the boxes are not aligned. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: A MWE, showing what you have so far, will give a starting point to the other members willing to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the package `tcolorbox` has changed. In the answer [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273223](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273223/110998), add the option `box align=top` to the tcolorboxes containing `#1` and `#2`, i.e., replace

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\topic{ m m g g g g g}
{
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,opacityframe=0,opacityback=0,opacitybacktitle=0, opacitytext=1,lefthand width=.3\textwidth]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!05,colframe=red!25,sidebyside align=top,width=\textwidth,before skip=0pt]
#1.\end{tcolorbox}%
\tcblower
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth,before skip=0pt]
#2
\end{tcolorbox}
```

by

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\topic{ m m g g g g g}
{
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,opacityframe=0,opacityback=0,opacitybacktitle=0, opacitytext=1,lefthand width=.3\textwidth]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!05,colframe=red!25,sidebyside align=top,width=\textwidth,box align=top,before skip=0pt]% <<< HERE
#1.\end{tcolorbox}%
\tcblower
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth,box align=top,before skip=0pt]% <<< HERE
#2
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\title{
\vspace{-3em}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,opacityback=0]
\begin{tcolorbox}
\Huge\sffamily Cornell Notes on Something   
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\vspace{-3em}
}

\date{}

\usepackage{background}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{red}
\SetBgContents{\rule[0em]{4pt}{\textheight}}
\SetBgHshift{-2.3cm}
\SetBgVshift{0cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\parindent=0pt

\DeclareDocumentCommand\topic{ m m g g g g g}
{
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,opacityframe=0,opacityback=0,opacitybacktitle=0, opacitytext=1,lefthand width=.3\textwidth]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!05,colframe=red!25,sidebyside align=top,width=\textwidth,box align=top,before skip=0pt]
#1.\end{tcolorbox}%
\tcblower
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth,box align=top,before skip=0pt]
#2
\end{tcolorbox}
\IfNoValueF {#3}{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
#3
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\IfNoValueF {#4}{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
#4
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\IfNoValueF {#5}{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
#5
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\IfNoValueF {#6}{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
#6
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\IfNoValueF {#7}{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
#7
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\def\summary#1{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=south,yshift=-1ex] at (current page text area.south) {% 
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%%%%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,opacityback=0]
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colframe=black,fonttitle=\large\bfseries\sffamily,sidebyside=true, nobeforeafter,before=\vfil,after=\vfil,colupper=black,sidebyside align=top, lefthand width=.95\textwidth,opacitybacktitle=1, opacitytext=1,
segmentation style={black!55,solid,opacity=0,line width=3pt},
title=Summary
]
#1
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle

\topic{This is a question}%
{The first piece of evidence is mandatory}%
{Now add up to five\ldots}%
{\ldots additional pieces of evidence.}

\topic{Here's another question.}{\lipsum[1]}%
{\lipsum[2]}%

\summary{This is a longer box that floats to the bottom of the page.}

\topic{Here's another question to begin the new page.}{\lipsum[3]}%
{\lipsum[4]}%
{\lipsum[5]}%

\summary{And another summary that will float to the bottom of the next page.}

\end{document}
```