# Modifying the Cornell Note Template

Tags: layout, paracol

I'm trying to modify the [Cornell Notes template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70570/cornell-notes-a-lyx-or-latex-solution-needed) to my specific needs.

1. Is there a way that the red line on the background breaks before and after a section and subsection title?

   I looked through the background documentation and didn't find a option to do that. Is there maybe an option with tikz?
2. What do I have to change so the red `\topic`
   boxes are always aligned with the first blue box?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\title{
    \vspace{-3em}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,opacityback=0]
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \Huge\sffamily Cornell Notes on Something   
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace{-3em}
}

\date{}

\usepackage{background}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{red}
\SetBgContents{\rule[0em]{4pt}{\textheight}}
\SetBgHshift{-2.3cm}
\SetBgVshift{0cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\parindent=0pt

\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\topic{ m m g g g g g}
{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,opacityframe=0,opacityback=0,opacitybacktitle=0, opacitytext=1,lefthand width=.3\textwidth]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!05,colframe=red!25,sidebyside align=top,width=\textwidth,before skip=0pt]
            #1.\end{tcolorbox}%
        \tcblower
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth,before skip=0pt]
            #2
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \IfNoValueF {#3}{
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
                #3
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }
        \IfNoValueF {#4}{
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
                #4
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }
        \IfNoValueF {#5}{
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
                #5
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }
        \IfNoValueF {#6}{
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
                #6
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }
        \IfNoValueF {#7}{
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\textwidth]
                #7
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }
    \end{tcolorbox}
}


\begin{document} 
    \maketitle
    
    \section{This is a long section title }
    \topic{This is a question}%
    {The first piece of evidence is mandatory}%
    {Now add up to five\ldots}%
    {\ldots additional pieces of evidence.}
    
    \section{This is an even longer section title}
    \topic{Here's another question.}{\lipsum[1]}%
    {\lipsum[2]}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you really sure about a command with seven argument, five of which are optional?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Without the five ```\IfNoValueF``` commands, it isn't possible to have more than one blue box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATED** after a follow up question

I propose a simpler code using the `paracol` package that meets both requirements.

[image: x]

[image: z]

Insert the question in the left column using `\question {<question text>}`

`\question` ends with `\switchcolumn`, so the following notes will go automatically to the right column. Insert as many notes as you like in the right column using `\note{<note text>}`.

When there are multiple questions in the same section, insert `\switchcolumn*` before the next question to synchronize the columns.
A small vertical space can be added to separate the question\notes groups.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{paracol} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}   

\newcommand{\question}[1]{% Ask the question
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!05,colframe=red!25,sidebyside align=top,width=\linewidth,before skip=1ex]
        #1.\end{tcolorbox}% 
        \switchcolumn % now write in the right column   
}

\newcommand{\note}[1]{% Add as many notes as you like
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!05,colframe=blue!10,width=\linewidth,before skip=1ex]
    #1
\end{tcolorbox}         
}   

\setcolumnwidth{0.50\textwidth/20pt,0.50\textwidth}% column separation =20pt
\setlength{\columnseprule}{3pt} % column width
\colseprulecolor{red}

\title{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[before skip = -\baselineskip, after skip =-\baselineskip]
        \centering\Huge\sffamily Cornell Notes on Something   
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\date{} 
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
    
\maketitle  

\section{This is a long section title}

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \question{This is a question} 
    \note{The first piece of evidence is mandatory}
    \note{Now add up to five\ldots}%
    \note{\ldots additional pieces of evidence.}
\end{paracol}

\section{This is an even longer section title}      

\begin{paracol}{2}  
    \question{Here's another question.}
    \note{\lipsum[1]}
    \note{\lipsum[2]}
\end{paracol}

\section{Some subject, several question}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \question{This is  question I}  
    \note{I The first piece of evidence is mandatory}
    \note{Now add up to five\ldots}%
    \note{\ldots additional pieces of evidence.}
    \vspace*{2ex}
    
    \switchcolumn* % go back to the left column ans synchronize <<<<
    \question{Here's  question II.}
    \note{II The first piece of evidence is mandatory}
    \note{Now add up to five\ldots}%
    \note{\ldots additional pieces of evidence.}
    \vspace*{2ex}
        
    \switchcolumn* % go back to the left column ans synchronize <<<<
    \question{And question III.}
    
    \note{III The first piece of evidence is mandatory}
    \note{Now add up to five\ldots}%
    \note{\ldots additional pieces of evidence.}
    \note{\ldots and more \ldots}
    \note{\ldots and more.}
\end{paracol}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! 
I only noticed one small detail. The red box is not perfectly aligned with the first blue box when more than ```paracol``` environment is used in the same section. This can be changed by changing ```before skip=0pt``` to ```before skip=6pt``` in the definition for the question. Probably not the best way to do this, but it works for me.

Comment: @danik Thank you for your feedback. I updated the answer with your suggestion and further simplified the code. (`\switchcolumn` is added by `\question`)