# How can I create a list with arguments passed to a macro?

Tags: macros, lists

Straight forward question:

```
\newcommand{\optaxis}[1][]{
   \ifemptyarg{#1}
    {\begin{axis} [xtick={0},   xmin=-1,  xmax =1,  xticklabels={#2},   box plot width=5mm]}
    {\begin{axis} [xtick={0,1}, xmin=-1,  xmax =2,  xticklabels={{#1},{#2}},    box plot width=5mm]}%

}
```

How can I get the part here to work correctly - `{{#1},{#2}}` - I am getting a variety of errors which I cannot seem to resolve. If I change that to `{test,test2}` it works and compiles fine.

The specific error message is:

> You meant to type ## instead of #, right?

---

edit:

I am trying to use from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58638/20940):

```
\makeatletter


\def\ifemptyarg#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % H. Oberdiek
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\optaxis}[1][]{
   \ifemptyarg{#2}
    {\begin{axis} [xtick={0},   xmin=-1,  xmax =1,  xticklabels={#1},   box plot width=5mm]}
    {\begin{axis} [xtick={0,1}, xmin=-1,  xmax =2,  xticklabels={{#1},{#2}},    box plot width=5mm]}
}
```

I want to be able to call this like:

```
\optaxis{test1}
\optaxis{test1, test2}
```

and have each called respectively.

Comment: I answered the specific error but if you made your example into a _complete_ (small) document that showed what you were trying to do we could suggest how to change the code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've updated the question with more.

Comment: There is only one parameter in `\optaxis{test1, test2}` which is `test1, test2`. If you used `\optaxis{test1}{test2}` then you would have two parameters.

Comment: See my answer, you just want one parameter which can have a comma, you have defined it as optional  so my examples use `[]` if you do not define it as optional then the argument would be surrounded by `{}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have defined a command with one argument

```
\newcommand{\optaxis}[1][]{
```

so you can't use `#2`

I suspect you just want

```
\newcommand{\optaxis}[1][]{%%%
 \begin{axis} [xtick={0},   xmin=-1,  xmax =1,  xticklabels={#1},   box plot width=5mm]}
```

so that

```
\optaxis
```

is `xticklabels={}`

```
\optaxis[test1]
```

is `xticklabels={test1}`

```
\optaxis[test1,test2]
```

is `xticklabels={test1,test2}`

Or perhaps no optional argument at all so

```
\newcommand{\optaxis}[1]{%%%
 \begin{axis} [xtick={0},   xmin=-1,  xmax =1,  xticklabels={#1},   box plot width=5mm]}
```

so that

```
\optaxis{test1}
```

is `xticklabels={test1}`

```
\optaxis{test1,test2}
```

is `xticklabels={test1,test2}`