# Two independent optional arguments for new commands

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'm trying to adapt the solution provided in [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument/314#314) to change the behavior of my new command. I'd like to use basic command to avoid some non basic packages.

I'm defining a command `\mysign` to produce my signature at the end of the document. But sometimes I need the date above and sometimes not. So I'd like to have an optional argument to insert it (for example`\mysign[date]`).

Also, sometimes I need to insert some personal ID and I'd like to have a second optional argument, but independent with the first one.

So, the result would be something like this:

- `\mysign` only the signature
- `\mysign[date]` the signature with date
- `\mysign[id]` the signature with ID
- `\mysign[date, id]` full signature

The problem is that `\@ifnextchar[` is working only for one option. I can not adjust to work only with second option.

Any idea?

Comment: Would a `key=value` approach be valid for you?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, thanks, but I have no idea what you are asking. Probably yes since I simply would like to turn on/off the date and ID on my signature.

Comment: I mean `\mysign` produces signature; `\mysign[date=<value>]` produces signature+date; `\mysign[id=<value>]` gives signature+id; `\mysign[date=<value>,id=<value>]` gives signature+date+id.

Comment: Great! It'll be very useful for me.

Comment: Doing with only one optional argument requires knowing the format of the ID, so that it's distinguishable from the date.

Comment: @egreg, in fact, the ID is an image and I'd like to insert it with `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 8):

A `key=value` approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\def\SigurId{}
\define@key{sigur}{date}{\def\SigurDate{#1}}
\define@boolkey{sigur}{id}{
  \ifKV@sigur@id
    \def\SigurId{\includegraphics[height=1.2ex,width=2cm]{example-image-a}}%
  \else
  \fi%
}

\makeatother
\newcommand\mysig[1][]{%
  \begingroup
    \setkeys{sigur}{date={},id=false}
    \setkeys{sigur}{#1}
    Sigur~\SigurDate\unskip~\SigurId\unskip
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\mysig 

\mysig[date={\today}]

\mysig[id=true]

\mysig[date=\today,id=true]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ow, thanks. Almost there. The ID is in fact an image, so I'm trying to adjust to make use of `\includegraphics` if the option `id` is passed. In your code I should pass the complete command to the value `id`?

Comment: @Sigur Will it always be the same image?

Comment: Yes, my scanned signature.

Comment: I'd defined a command to the whole command to include the graphics and now I can pass the key `id=\myid`.

Comment: @Sigur please see my updated answer with a new boolean key for the image.

Answer (score 6):

From the comments to the [answer of Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123184/16967) I conclude that the optional argument ID is constant and rather a flag. Then LaTeX also knows an optional star as syntax element. The following example defines `\mysign` without the need of further packages the following way:

- If a star follows, then the signature ID is set.
- If an optional argument follows, then the date is set.
- If the optional argument is empty, then `\today` is used as date.

The example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\SetId}{%
  % tabular is only used for vertical centering
  % and ghostscript's example tiger.eps is the dummy
  % for the real scanned signature
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}%
    \includegraphics[height=2em,trim=0 50mm 0 0,clip]{tiger}%
  \end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand*{\mysign}{%
  \@ifstar{%
    \let\@DoId=\SetId
    \@mysign
  }{%
    \let\@DoId=\relax
    \@mysign
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@mysign}[1][\relax]{%
  Signature%
  \def\@mysign@relax{\relax}%
  \def\@mysign@date{#1}%
  \ifx\@mysign@date\@mysign@relax
  \else
    , %
    \ifx\@mysign@date\@empty
      \today
    \else
      #1%
    \fi
  \fi
  \ifx\@DoId\relax
  \else
    , %   
    \@DoId
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb|\mysign| & \mysign \\
\verb|\mysign*| & \mysign* \\
\verb|\mysign[]| & \mysign[] \\
\verb|\mysign[2001-02-03]| & \mysign[2001-02-03] \\
\verb|\mysign*[]| & \mysign*[] \\
\verb|\mysign*[2001-02-03]| & \mysign*[2001-02-03] \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Ow, many thanks. I'm learning a lot with these kind of solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution based again on a key-based interface: it exploits `pgfkeys`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

% key definition
\newif\ifbaseline
\pgfkeys{/signature/.cd, baseline/.is if=baseline}
\pgfkeys{/signature/.cd,
  date/.initial={},
  date/.get=\signdate,
  date/.store in=\signdate,
  id/.initial={},
  id/.get=\id,
  id/.store in=\id,
}

% Basic command
\newcommand{\signature}[2][]{
\pgfkeys{signature/.cd,
  date={},
  id={},
  baseline=false,
  #1}
#2\space\signdate\space%
\ifbaseline
 \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\node[inner sep=0pt]{\id};
\else
 \id
\fi%
}

\begin{document}
\signature{Sigur}

\signature[date=\today]{Sigur}

\signature[id={\includegraphics[width=2em,height=2em]{example-image}}]{Sigur}

\signature[baseline,id={\includegraphics[width=2em,height=2em]{example-image}}]{Sigur}

\signature[baseline,
  id={\includegraphics[width=2em,height=2em]{example-image}},
  date={June 28, 2013}]{Sigur}

\signature[id={\includegraphics[width=2em,height=2em]{example-image}},
  date={June 28, 2013}]{Sigur}
\end{document}
```

TikZ is not really needed, actually it can be loaded `pgfkeys` in its place, but then I enjoyed the possibility to put the picture aligned on the baseline.

The result:

[image]

Comment: the `twoopt` package provides `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand` and `\providecommand` variants, that all accept two optional arguments.

Comment: @wasteofspace: what if they are three or six? With key-based approaches it's just matter of defining new keys. Please, also consider that there's the `xparse` package able to define commands with more optional arguments, but I really believe that a key-based approach is the best.

Comment: This is really the only right approach.

Answer (score 2):

The poor man's solution:

```
\newcommand\mysig[3][Sigur]{#2 #1 #3}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mysig[3][Sigur]{#2 #1 #3}

\begin{document}

\mysig{date}{id}

\mysig{date}

\mysig{}{id}

\mysig

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Poor, but with rich soul. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what about doing something like:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\mysign}[2]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{#1\\}%
    SIGNATURE CODE%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\\#2}}
```

and then just invoke with the fields you don't want to use blank

i.e. `\mysign{date}{}` fot just date, etc...

Comment: Do you know if the package `ifthen` comes with basic install?

Comment: according to `apt-file` it comes packaged in `texlive-latex-base`so it should come by default