# Conditionally Remove Brackets

Tags: macros, conditionals

I'm trying to create a command with an optional argument using

```
\newcommand{\Af}[1]{{\mathbf{A}_{(#1)}}
```

where the argument is a number.

However, I'd like that if no argument is given the bracket were dropped.

**Question**

How could I define a command which decides whether or not write the brackets?

Comment: In addition to the more sophisticated answers below, there are tricks you can do with ifthen.sty.  That's what I would have done.

Comment: Related: [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another solution using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \Af }{ o }{%
    A\IfValueT{#1}{_{(#1)}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{ \Bf }{ d() }{%
    A\IfValueT{#1}{_{(#1)}}%
}

\begin{document}
no argument: $\Af$

with argument: $\Af[x]$

no argument: $\Bf$

with argument: $\Bf(x)$
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

`xparse` uses a different (an in my eyes easier and more flexible) syntax to define a command. The second argument of `\NewDocumentCommand` takes a list defining the arguments, e.g. `o` for an optional an `m` for a mandatory argument. With `\If(No)Value(TF)` you can test whether the argument has a value. `(TF)` can be `T` or `F` to test only one case or `TF` to differentiate between both the latter case has there arguments, e.g. `{#1}{true code}{false code}`. With `d` as argument specifier (see `\Bf` definition) you can even define the delimiting symbols, `()` in this case, so the code equals the output even more.

As daleif said you can add a `\smash` to the subscript to prevent it form affecting the line spacing.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{ \Afs }{ o }{%
    A\IfValueT{#1}{_{\smash{(#1)}}}%
}
```

without `\smash` (exaggerating example using `\sum` and `\left…\right` to get flexible parens).
[image: without smash]

with `\smash`
[image: with smash]

Comment: It might be an idea to add `\smash` to the `()`'s because they have a tendency to affect line spacing when used in sub- and superscript.

Comment: There is also `\IfValueT` that's perhaps more intuitive than `\IfNoValueF`, in this case.

Comment: @egreg: O … that’s right :-).

Comment: @daleif: I’ll add this.

Comment: I would not add the left/right part, too much risk of them ending too large. I would only smash the () not the contents

Comment: @daleif: I removed it. I used it to demonstrate the `\smash` and didn’t think about removing it afterwards …

Answer (score 17):

Since you want an optional argument I think you should use the presence of the argument (rather than it being empty) as the test so

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand\Af{\@ifnextchar[\@Af\@@Af}

\def\@@Af{\mathbf{A}}
\def\@Af[#1]{\@@Af_{(#1)}}

\makeatother

...

\Af ... \Af[x] ...
```

Answer (score 14):

I usually use `etoolbox`

Something like (note your example does not use an optional argument)

```
 \newcommand\Af[1][]{\mathbf{A}\ifblank{#1}{}{_{(#1))}}}
```

ought to do the trick (untested)

Usage:

```
$\Af$  will just give $\mathbf{A}$
```

and

```
$\Af[n]$ will give $\mathbf{A}_{(n)}$
```

BTW: One can do even cooler things with the `xparse` package such as instead of `$\Af[n]$` we can use `$\Af_{n}$` to get the same result (see the argument type `e` in the `xparse` manual), aka we pick up the `n` from the subscript and wrap `()` around it.

Comment: I recommend to add some usage examples as well.