# How do I use the etoolbox package to check if an argument to a macro was defined?

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I saw [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63041), which uses the `etoolbox` package to create a macro with an optional argument. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\mymacrotwo[2][]{
  \ifstrempty{#2}{
    #1: none
  }{
    #1: #2
  }
}

\begin{document}
\mymacrotwo{hello}

\mymacrotwo{hello}{world}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

```
: hello
: hello world
```

Not only are the colons in the wrong place, but it doesn't display the `none` if the second argument isn't defined. What's the problem?

I also tried this variant:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[2]{#1 \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdef{#2}} } {#2} {none}}

\begin{document}
\mymacro{hello}

\mymacro{hello}{world}
\end{document}
```

but this outputs:

```
hello
hello orldworld
```

which clearly isn't right either.

Comment: Your definition requires the optional argument `#1` to be supplied using `[]`. As in `\mymacrotwo[hello]{world}`.

Comment: @Werner Ah the problem was because I used `[2][]` instead of just `[2]`, I guess, right?

Comment: Even with `\newcommand{\mymacrotwo}[2]{...}` you can't use `\mymacrotwo{hello}` and hope that `#2` is considered empty.

Comment: @egreg Will that result in undefined behavior? If I use just `[2]`, and don't make any other changes to my document, everything seems to work.

Comment: @fortranuser: Perhaps provide examples of the types of input and expected output in your post. From there, community members might help you in your formal definition.

Comment: @Werner I'm just planning to use this with text input, and output just like in the example (maybe with formatting like `\textbf`, but probably not). Is there anything else I should provide?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If a TeX macro is defined as having two arguments, TeX will *always* assign some token to both arguments, or raise an error.

Defining

```
\newcommand\mymacrotwo[2]{
  \ifstrempty{#2}{
    #1: none
  }{
    #1: #2
  }
}
```

has already some weak points, because you're adding several spaces which will show up in the printout. Better would be

```
\newcommand\mymacrotwo[2]{%
  \ifstrempty{#2}%
   {%
    #1: none%
   }%
   {%
    #1: #2%
   }%
}
```

How to align the braces for the alternatives is a matter of personal taste, but end-of-lines should be masked off unless you *do* want a space to show up.

Let's see what happens if you type

```
\mymacrotwo{hello} and some text
```

The macro has *two* arguments; the first one is determined to be `hello`, because a brace is scanned; the second argument will be `a`: when looking for an argument, TeX takes the first *non space* token it finds, unless it is `{`; in this case the argument is whatever appears up to the matching `}`.

If you call

```
\mymacrotwo{hello}
and some text
```

it would be exactly the same, because TeX converts the end-of-line into a space and spaces are ignored when looking for an argument.

<sub>TeXnical note: here I'm talking about *undelimited* arguments, the kind that is looked for when macros defined with `\newcommand` are concerned.</sub>

Leaving a blank line wouldn't help either: with

```
\mymacrotwo{hello}

and some text
```

the second argument would be `\par`, because TeX converts an empty line into a `\par` token.

Let's verify it. I'll use a simplified version of the macro that just prints its arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mymacrotwo}[2]{%
  ``{\ttfamily \#1 is \detokenize{#1}, \#2 is \detokenize{#2}}''%
}

\begin{document}
\mymacrotwo{hello} and some text

\mymacrotwo{hello}
and some text

\mymacrotwo{hello}

and some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

So if you want to use your macro as intended, you *must* call it either

```
\mymacrotwo{hello}{}
```

or

```
\mymacrotwo{hello}{world}
```

Actually, with `xparse` one could define a macro with the characteristics you'd like, but it's debatable whether this fits into LaTeX syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mymacrotwo}{ m g }
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
   {%
    #1: none%
   }
   {
    #1: #2%
   }%
 }

\begin{document}

\mymacrotwo{hello} and some text

\mymacrotwo{hello}{world} and some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

I surely wouldn't recommend using this feature.

Comment: I'd also add that the definition in the question (`\newcommand\mymacrotwo[2][]{...}`) means that the first argument is optional and defautls to the empty string. So it can/should be used like `\mymacrotwo{hello}` or `\mymacrotwo[world]{hello}`.