# Remove `glossaries` comma after the entries description if no units are provided

Tags: glossaries

I have created a `glossaries` nomenclature style that, in my main document, works perfectly and within my space constraints. However, I am facing an issue when a `\newglossaryentry{...}` doesn't have a `symbol` field i.e. the nomenclature is unitless.

See this MWE image:

[image]

I tried to remove it using `etoolbox`'s `\ifstrempty` using this answer by [GLemyre](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567646/273733) like so:

```
\newglossarystyle{nomenS}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular}[l]{@{}%
    p{\dimexpr.1\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.8\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep}@{}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}\ifstrempty{\glossentrysymbol{##1}}{}{, \glossentrysymbol{##1}}%
        \tabularnewline%
    }%
}
```

but I am unsure if the `symbol` field is even a string nor am I comfortable yet with `\ifx` etc with LaTeX. How can I change my `nomenS` glossary style to only include the comma if the `symbol` field exists please?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossary{nomen}{nom}{ntn}{Nomenclature}

\newglossarystyle{nomenS}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular}[l]{@{}%
    p{\dimexpr.1\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.8\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep}@{}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}, \glossentrysymbol{##1}%
        \tabularnewline%
    }%
}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{units}
    {%
    name={$\Delta\Phi_0$},
    description={Superhelical phase offset},
    symbol={°},
    sort={abp},
    type=nomen,
    }

\newglossaryentry{nounits}
    {%
    name={$C_\alpha$},
    description={No units},
    sort={ca},
    symbol={},
    type=nomen,
    }

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=nomen,style=nomenS]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glossaries offers a dedicated test:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossary{nomen}{nom}{ntn}{Nomenclature}

\newglossarystyle{nomenS}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular}[l]{@{}%
    p{\dimexpr.1\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.8\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep}@{}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}\ifglshassymbol{##1}{, \glossentrysymbol{##1}}{}%
        \tabularnewline%
    }%
}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{units}
    {%
    name={$\Delta\Phi_0$},
    description={Superhelical phase offset},
    symbol={°},
    sort={abp},
    type=nomen,
    }

\newglossaryentry{nounits}
    {%
    name={$C_\alpha$},
    description={No units},
    sort={ca},
    symbol={},
    type=nomen,
    }

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=nomen,style=nomenS]
\end{document}
```

[image]