# How to get a curved arrow pointing left and right?

Tags: symbols

I need something like `$\curvearrowright$`, but pointing in both directions.  This is for a commutative diagram.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site! How about `\curvearrowleftright` from `mathabx`?

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks, the only problem with that one is it does not curve quite enough.  Instead, I just learned to use mathrlap in mathtools, then overlayed the left and right curved arrows. I had to mess with the spacing to get them to align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two variants: One stolen from Heiko  [from his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163010/11232)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand{\myarrow}{\scalebox{1.2}[2]{$\mathclap{\curvearrowleft}\mkern2.2mu
                                                 \mathclap{\curvearrowright}$}}

% from package mathabx:
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\downtouparrow}{3}{mathb}{"FF}

\newcommand*{\Myarrow}{%
  \scalebox{1}[-2]{$\mathclap{\downtouparrow}\mkern0.5mu
                                                 \mathclap{\reflectbox{$\downtouparrow$}}$}
}
\begin{document}
\[
 \myarrow 
\]

\[
\Myarrow
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice curvy arrows :)