# Latex \@author With ifthenelse

Tags: titles

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \begin{center}%
        \let \footnote \thanks
        {\Large \MakeUppercase{\@title} \par}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@author}{}}{no author}%
            {\vskip 1.5em\textsc{\setstretch{1.32}\@author\\\hfill}\par}%
    \end{center}
    \par
\vskip 4em\noindent}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

However, it won't compile. Taking out the `\ifthenelse` works (can be tested by putting a `%` infront of it), but I really need to have it in. The error is as follows:

```
/tmp/gummi_V2UOCX:32: Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.32 \maketitle
```

Comment: Instead of providing only a code snippet, please supply us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that clear shows the context in which the error occurs. This should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- You're using `\ifthenelse` which requires the [`ifthen` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) (or [`xifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen)).
- The same goes for `\setstretch` which requires [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace).

However, a bigger problem is the test to see whether `\@author` is empty `{}`. The default LaTeX document classes define `\@author` to *not* be empty, even though no `\author` is specified. In fact, if no `\author` is specified, `\@author` looks like this (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}}
\def\@author{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\author given}}
```

`\author` just redefines `\@author` to contain the author name, otherwise it's default output is a warning `No \author given`. The following *just* changes that part, since I'm not sure what you want to do with the rest of the title formatting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace

\makeatletter
\let\@emptyauthor\@author
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \begin{center}%
        \let \footnote \thanks
        {\Large \MakeUppercase{\@title} \par}%
        \ifx\@author\@emptyauthor
          no author%
        \else% \author is supplied
          \vskip 1.5em\textsc{\setstretch{1.32}\@author\\\hfill}\par
        \fi%
    \end{center}
    \par
\vskip 4em\noindent}

\makeatother

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The idea is to capture what `\@author` looks like at the start of your preamble. Then you can check the macro definitions exactly and branch/condition accordingly. `\@emptyauthor` stores `\@author` without any modifications and the text `\ifx\@author\@emptyauthor <true/no author> \else <false/author> \fi` provides the condition.

However, it would be easier to specify `\author{no author}`... really.

---

For adding the date as another branched output, you can use

```
\makeatletter
\def\ifemptyarg#1{% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308/5764
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % H. Oberdiek
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\let\@emptyauthor\@author
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \begin{center}%
        \let \footnote \thanks
        {\Large \MakeUppercase{\@title} \par}%
        \ifx\@author\@emptyauthor
          no author%
        \else% \author is supplied
          \vskip 1.5em\textsc{\setstretch{1.32}\@author\\\hfill}\par
        \fi%
        \par\expandafter\ifemptyarg\expandafter{\@date}{no date}{\@date}%
    \end{center}
    \par
\vskip 4em\noindent}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble.

[image]

```
\title{A title}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Is there a way to do it for the date too? Doing \date{\today} and the method similar to your description doesn't work, because \today is the default value.

Comment: @user2195592: I'm not sure I follow. Do you want `\date{\today}` to be equivalent to `no date` and `\date{<something else>}` to be equivalent to `date: <something else>`?

Comment: If I do \date{}, it should show 'no date' in this case. Else, it will show the value of \date.

Comment: @user2195592: I've added a date-related branching.