# How can I remove an empty caption line

Tags: spacing, floats, captions, memoir

I'm generating LaTex automagically from a lengthy document that is written in the multimarkdown language, compiled by a software package called Scrivener. It's a workflow that works well, but this is one of the issues I'm hitting. I don't want to have to replace / delete numerous caption command each time I compile to LaTex.

The MWE below illustrates the issue.

This remove `Figure n:` and caption from included graphic. However, it leaves a blank line, which makes the images spacing appear gauche. Is there a simple way to remove the blank line , without inserting space adjustments, each time a figure is used Thanks.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{mwe}                    %   for dummy images
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption} %   remove figure captions

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}                   
  \caption{}
  \end{figure}
   This is first text after caption.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't write `\caption{}`..?

Comment: @jon see my edited explanation of how my workflow creates this issue

Comment: Will any figures need a caption?  If not, isn't it easy to do something like `\let\caption\relax`?  (Probably need to do that after `\usepackage{caption}`.) Note: I don't know if Scrivener allows you to define arbitrary commands or not, or fiddle with the preamble...

Comment: Thanks. I don't envisage any figures requiring a caption, no. I tried `\let\caption\relax` in the preamble, but that returns error: `\caption undefined`…

Comment: Are you *always* putting `\includegraphics[..]{...} \caption{..}`? If so, one can use this "pattern" to perform certain replacements. Do you sometimes use `\caption` with a non-empty argument?

Comment: @jon : the error is returned w/r/to my MWE, not my document… yet you say it's working for you. I have `\let\caption\relax` on the ensuing line after `\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}`

Comment: @jon: yes, I have full control over the preamble

Comment: @Werner I don't want to achieve this effect by a secondary find and replace: because of (described) workflow, I (re)compile / regenerate the LaTex file repeatedly, often several times a day.

Comment: @jon : where would I `\listfiles`? Terminal (OSX)?

Comment: Put `\listfiles` in the preamble; then check the `.log` after compilation.  I have, e.g.:  `memoir.cls 2013/05/30 v3.7b` and `caption.sty 2013/05/02 v3.3-89`.

Comment: I have just run TexLive, which is how I obtained my version of Tex and it instructed me to upgrade to TexLive2013, so complying now… (takes >20mins)

Comment: log returns: `caption.sty    2012/02/19 v3.2f` and `memoir.cls    2011/03/06 v3.6j configurable book, report, article document cl
`

Comment: Well those are older versions that may not interact so well.  A variant on the `\let` command would be to do `\def\caption{}`, which will tyrannically overwrite any previous (or not) definitions of `\caption`...

Comment: @johnbrc: My suggestion is not to use a secondary search-and-replace, but let LaTeX perform that. I just want to know what the general situation is like. You can also modify `\caption` to pick up whether it's argument is empty, and condition accordingly. More information in terms of the general situation is required though...

Comment: @Werner general situation is as you suggest: the pattern is regularly, I believe, exhaustively as you describe, but yes there are sometimes when I would *prefer* the option to use `\caption` with a non-empty argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides its own interface for caption management, and there may be some clashes when using it in conjunction with [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) (see section **10.13 The class versus the `caption` package (and its friends)**, p 206 of the [`memoir` user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)).

However, you can update `\caption` to grab its contents, evaluate whether the argument is empty/not, and condition accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{mwe}                    %   for dummy images
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption} %   remove figure captions

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58638/5764
\makeatletter
\def\ifemptyarg#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % H. Oberdiek
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother

\let\oldcaption\caption
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\caption}[2][]{%
    \ifemptyarg{#2}{}{\oldcaption[#1]{#2}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}                   
  \caption{}
\end{figure}
This is first text after caption.

\newpage

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}                   
  \caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}
This is first text after caption.

\end{document}
```

If you're not using the optional argument of `\caption` in your workflow, then the redefinition could be a bit simpler:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\caption}[1]{%
    \ifemptyarg{#1}{}{\oldcaption{#1}}%
  }%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't use captions anywhere, redefine `\caption` to do nothing.

```
\renewcommand{\caption}{}
```

Which I think will do what you want.

Comment: that looks promising…will test on whole document before upmarking

Comment: @johnbrc -- If you are getting `\caption undefined` with my suggestions, you won't be able to `\renewcommand` it either since there is no command (yet) to REnew.

Comment: This works on the MWE…but not on my document. Is that what your comment @jon implies I should expect?

Comment: Try the renewcommand right before begin document?