# Shouldn't this table span the whole page width?

Tags: tabularx, width

I have this table definition as part of a invoice

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[ht]{lXrr}%
```

It worked fine for years until I have a very short word in the `X` column for the first time.
Now my table is very small in width and centered horizontally on the page.

In my expectation the `X` column should fill up all space until the width of the table reaches the width of the page except the margins.

I have read about workarounds specifying something like `1.2\textwidth`, but I don't like that, because the table is a template included via `\include`, so it would affect all my invoices.

I also tried `\linewidth`, `\hsize` and `\columnwidth`, but everything results in the same layout.

**Is there a way to make the only `X` column expand so that it uses all available space?**

[image: Actual and expected output]

Complete included table definition (Rechnungstabelle.tex):

```
\newcommand{\Rechnungstabelle}[4]{%
vielen Dank für Ihren Auftrag.
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[ht]{lXrr}%
\toprule%
\bf{Anzahl} & \bf{Bezeichnung} & \bf{Einzelpreis} & \bf{Gesamtpreis} \\%
\midrule%
#1%
\bottomrule%
& \bf{Rechnungsbetrag}  & & \bf{\EUR{#2}} \\%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{& Enthaltene MwSt. 19\% & & \EUR{#3} \\}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{& * Enthaltene MwSt. 7\% & & \EUR{#4} \\}%
\end{tabularx}%
}
```

Changing the table header row to

```
\bf{Anzahl} & \bf{Bezeichnung} \hspace{\textwidth} & \bf{Einzelpreis} & \bf{Gesamtpreis} \\%
```

is a workaround, but I don't think that would be good TeX style.

Minimum example for reproducing:

```
\documentclass[ fontsize=12pt, 
                paper=a4,
                foldmarks=TBMPL,
                fromalign=center,
                ngerman
                ]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\input{Rechnungstabelle}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}

\Rechnungstabelle{
    1,0 h & Do something & \EUR{99,00} & \EUR{99,00} \\ 
    }
    {99,00}
    {}{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: The problem here is the [`ltablex` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltablex) - it modifies `tabularx`. Do you need it? There's [`ltxtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) which provides similar functionality.

Comment: @Werner: hmm, removing `ltablex` corrects `Rechnungstabelle` and destroys my footer. I think I can fix the footer. If you give that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. Without knowing what your footer looks like (you didn't include that in your MWE), it's hard to say why it breaks.

Comment: @Werner: I could fix the footer, even without asking another question here :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ltablex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltablex) is the culprit here, as it modifies the `tabularx` environment. If you're not using it, remove it, or consider [`ltxtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) which provides similar functionality using a different environment.

You may be interested in the following definition of `\Rechnungstabelle` (note the paragraph break before `\noindent`):

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58638/5764
\makeatletter
\def\ifemptyarg#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % H. Oberdiek
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Rechnungstabelle}[4]{%
  vielen Dank für Ihren Auftrag.

  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXrr}%
    \toprule%
    \textbf{Anzahl} & \textbf{Bezeichnung} & \textbf{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Gesamtpreis} \\%
    \midrule%
    #1%
    \bottomrule%
    & \textbf{Rechnungsbetrag}  & & \textbf{\EUR{#2}} \\%
    \ifemptyarg{#3}{}{& Enthaltene MwSt. 19\% & & \EUR{#3} \\}%
    \ifemptyarg{#4}{}{& * Enthaltene MwSt. 7\% & & \EUR{#4}}%
  \end{tabularx}%
}
```

I've dropped the use of `\ifthenelse` (see [Why is the `ifthen` package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764)) and used `\ifemptyarg` from [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58638/5764).

Comment: Also `\par` should be added before `\noindent`.

Comment: More detailed answer than I expected. Thanks for all the additional tipps and obsolete hints.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it with the `\keepXColumns` command provided by `ltablex` itself (rtfm ;-) )

> Another feature that has been added is to treat the X
>   columns like `l` columns if the table contents would allow
>   that to happen without exceeding the specified width of
>   the table. In other words, the specified width is 
>   treated as the maximum allowed and not the exact width 
>   of the table. This feature is the default but can be 
>   disabled (or enabled) with `\keepXColumns` (or `\convertXColumns`).

Best, 
Chris