# Redefine optional argument of \item in enumitem

Tags: lists, enumitem, optional-arguments

I am using the `enumitem` package, and I would like to redefine the optional argument of the `\item` command.  By default, the optional argument accepts text to replace the default label.  I never exercise this option.  Instead, I would like the optional argument to accept a number, say 10, which is then printed at the beginning of the item paragraph in the form (10 points).  The label itself is not effected and still registers the label counter. I'm aware that this behavior is implemented by the `Exam Document Class`, but I prefer to customize my own lists via `enumitem`.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you should have a look into the exsheets package http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exsheets/exsheets_en.pdf

Comment: Do you need the same points on all items? You can put an example to clarify your needs.

Comment: @aboAmmar The points will vary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xparse}

\makeatletter
% enumitem-related constructions
\newlist{pointslist@}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[pointslist@]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
% Create list emulator
\newenvironment{pointslist}[1][]
  {\begin{pointslist@}[#1]% \begin{pointslist}[<opts>]
     \let\olditem\item% Store \item in \olditem
     \RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{o}{% Redefine \item to
       \olditem\leavevmode% ... call \olditem...
       \IfNoValueF{##1}{(##1~points)}% ...and possibly (.. points)
     }}
  {\end{pointslist@}}% \end{pointslist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pointslist}
  \item This is some item
  \item[10] This is item is worth something
  \item Just another item
\end{pointslist}

\end{document}
```

In principle, we create an [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)-defined list - `pointslist@` - and set everything accordingly. Then we create a new *environment* that would emulate the list, only to redefine `\item` to suit your needs.

The redefinition of `\item` is such that it always sets the original `\item` (`\olditem` in the redefinition) before checking whether you supplied your optional argument. If there was an optional argument specified, it sets the appropriate message.

---

A rudimentary LaTeX2e implementation for the [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) command redefinition might resemble

```
\newenvironment{pointslist}[1][]
  {\begin{pointslist@}[#1]%
     \let\olditem\item
     \renewcommand{\item}[1][\relax]{%
       \olditem\leavevmode
       \ifx\relax##1\relax\else(##1~points)\fi%
     }}
  {\end{pointslist@}}
```

The only test would be to see whether the user supplied an optional argument or not. Options for checking this is available in [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308/5764).

Comment: This looks very nice, Werner, although I'll need to study it.  Where does the `xparse` come in?

Comment: @steven_nevets: [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an easy-to-use interface for checking the use/existence of optional arguments. There are pure LaTeX2e equivalents, but `xparse` is the future... :)

Comment: Thanks, Werner, for the incorporated documentation and LaTeX2e equivalents. That is very much appreciated.

Comment: how to provide an optional argument for pointslist? e.g. `\begin{pointslist}[(2)] \item ... \end{pointslist}` to start from 2 instead of 1.

Comment: @user19832: Use `\begin{pointslist}[start=2] \item ... \end{pointslist}`. This is thanks to [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).