# I want to create a new command for making a table, parameters in the command would fill up the table

Tags: tables, macros

For making play cards, I need to make a table of 5 by 5 cells. First row and first column would always be the same. But the other cells would depend off the card.

So it would be nice to gave a command like:
\test{3,1,6,1,2,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,5,7,5,4}
that would generate table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\test[3][]%
{\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | c }
\hline
 & lente & zomer & herfst & winter \\ 
\hline 
B & 3 & 1 & 6 & 1 \\ 
G & 2 & 2 & #2 & #3 \\ 
D & 4 & 3 & 4 & 3 \\ 
S & 5 & 7 & 5 & 4 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 }

\test{4}{6} 
\end{document}
```

I can do this with more parameters, but why do I have to make 3 options for only 2 values? So I tested with:

```
\newcommand\test[1][]%
```

and the

```
\test{4}
```

but it didn't work. What is causing this problem? Thanks
[image]

Comment: I don't really know what you want here. A macro that takes a comma-separated list that creates the table? But why would you want that if a large portion of the table remains fixed?

Comment: Have a look at pgfplotstable :)

Comment: @Werner I want a table with sixteen different values, each table would have 16 different values, depending on the card. AND, but I didn't want to make the code to cluttered, B - G - D and S, are pictures of country flags ;-)

Comment: @Arne: Do `\test{4}{6}` like in your first example works without problem. What do you want different from this?

Comment: @Werner understanding why I need 3 parameters, the fill in two things, when I type    \newcommand\test[2][]%
and     G & 2 & 2 & #1 & #2 \\ 
it does not do it correctly

Comment: @Arne: You need `\newcommand{\test}[2]{...}` not `\newcommand{\test}[2][]{...}`. Note that the first doesn't have an extra `[]`.

Comment: @Werner Ok just a stupid syntax mistake. :-( , but now :)

Comment: @Arne: I'm not sure whether that answers your question or not. If so, I could write up a short answer and some reference material.

Comment: @Werner No thanks, my problem is solved. maybe I should delete my question?

Comment: @Arne: As a reference, see [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308/5764).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just be misinterpreting the way a command is constructed.

```
\newcommand{<cmd>}[<num>]{<stuff>}
```

creates a macro `<cmd>` with `<num>` mandatory arguments. So, `\newcommand{\test}[2]{<stuff>}` would be used `\test{<first>}{<second>}` where `<first>` is referenced as `#1` in `<stuff>` and `<second>` as `#2`. If you use

```
\newcommand{<cmd>}[<num>][<something>]{<stuff>}
```

then `<cmd>` takes `<num>`-1 *mandatory* arguments, and a *single, optional* argument. So, `\newcommand{\test}[2][something]{<stuff>}` can be used in the following two ways

```
\test{else} % <------- Single mandatory argument; optional argument will
            %          default to "something". That is, #1={something},
            %          #2={else}.
\test[someone]{else} % Optional + mandatory argument. #1={someone},
                     % #2={else}.
```

For more information on command definitions, see [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308/5764).

In your particular case, you would need

```
\newcommand\test[2]%
  {\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | c }
     \hline
     & lente & zomer & herfst & winter \\ 
     \hline 
     B & 3 & 1 & 6 & 1 \\ 
     G & 2 & 2 & #1 & #2 \\ 
     D & 4 & 3 & 4 & 3 \\ 
     S & 5 & 7 & 5 & 4 \\ 
     \hline
   \end{tabular}%
 }
```

No need for a `table` floating environment (as far as I can see). Also, consider using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for neat `tabular` representation.

Comment: Now I understand the command principe! May way of learning LaTeX is more the "copy-way". Seeing, copying, adapting, understanding... but sometimes the last step is missing. Didn't knew booktabs... Thanks for the tip and https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf opened my eyes

Answer (score 1):

For just sixteen positions, some brute force is sufficient; for longer sets of data a cleverer splitting of the list would be the way to go. In the example I show the “short” version and the longer one for comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cards}{ m }
 {
  \arne_card_distribution:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \arne_card_distribution:n
 {
  \begin{tabular}{ *{5}{c} }
  \toprule
  & lente & zomer & herfst & winter \\
  \cmidrule{2-5}
  B & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 1 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 2 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 3 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 4 } \\
  G & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 5 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 6 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 7 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 8 } \\
  D & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 9 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 10 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 11 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 12 } \\
  S & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 13 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 14 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 15 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 16 } \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cards{3,1,6,1,2,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,5,7,5,4}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | c }
\hline
 & lente & zomer & herfst & winter \\ 
\hline 
B & 3 & 1 & 6 & 1 \\ 
G & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\ 
D & 4 & 3 & 4 & 3 \\ 
S & 5 & 7 & 5 & 4 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you don't like the `booktabs` way, then it should be easy to provide the necessary changes.

[image]