# border/frame around table use ExplSyntaxOn

Tags: tables

From topic: [I want to create a new command for making a table, parameters in the command would fill up the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273439/i-want-to-create-a-new-command-for-making-a-table-parameters-in-the-command-wou)

How can i draw border/frame around table?

Minimal code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cards}{ m }
 {
  \arne_card_distribution:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \arne_card_distribution:n
 {
  \begin{tabular}{ *{5}{c} }
  \toprule
  A & B & C & D  \\
  \cmidrule{2-5}
  \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 1 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 2 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 3 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 4 } \\
  \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 5 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 6 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 7 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 8 } \\
  \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 9 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 10 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 11 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 12 } \\
  \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 13 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 14 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 15 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 16 } \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cards{x,y,z,w/m,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: This was possible by using `tkz`, refer the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10224/table-with-rounded-corners, I am not sure about `ExplSyntaxOn`

Comment: @MadyYuvi thanks. i tried but not work with Explsyntaxon. Thanks

Comment: You can use TikZ but you have to make sure to replace all spaces in option names with `~`.