# Set separator to a pipe | (default is comma) for \newdocumentcommand in ExplSyntaxOn

Tags: expl3, database

In the code from the topic [I want to create a new command for making a table, parameters in the command would fill up the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273439/i-want-to-create-a-new-command-for-making-a-table-parameters-in-the-command-wou)

The separator is a comma in:

```
\cards{3,1,6,1,2,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,5,7,5,4}
```

But in my data, there are many entries containing a comma: for example "red, blue Tshirt"

How can I change the separator to pipe `|` so that I can type the following?

```
\cards{3|1|6|1|2|2|3|2|4|3|4|3|5|7|5|4}
```

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cards}{ m }
 {
  \arne_card_distribution:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \arne_card_distribution:n
 {
  \begin{tabular}{ *{5}{c} }
  \toprule
  & lente & zomer & herfst & winter \\
  \cmidrule{2-5}
  B & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 1 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 2 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 3 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 4 } \\
  G & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 5 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 6 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 7 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 8 } \\
  D & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 9 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 10 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 11 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 12 } \\
  S & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 13 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 14 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 15 }
    & \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 16 } \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cards{3,1,6,1,2,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,5,7,5,4}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Will your table always have 4 rows and 4 columns, or it may increase depending on the number of items in the argument?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thanks.can change number of items. I want to change seperator between data in \cards..

Comment: Yes, that's quite easy to do, I'll post an answer. I want to know what do you want to happen if you pass, say, 12 items to `\cards`, or 20 items, instead of 16. Should the table change in size or should there be an error?

Comment: You are right. The table size can 12,16,20,24,28..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a slightly (over?)worked version of the table. I made it a bit more flexible regarding the number of rows and columns you can use.

The `\cards` command now takes an optional argument plus three mandatory arguments:

```latex
\cards[<key-val>]{<header row>}{<first column>}{<table body>}
```

The optional argument lets you set the separator using `sep=<sep>` (default is `sep=|`) and the alignment of the table cells using `align=<token>` (default is `align=c`). The `<header row>` is a list of `<sep>`-separated items which will be typeset at the top of the table, preceded by an empty cell. The `<first column>` is also a list of `<sep>`-separated items which will be typeset at each row of the table, starting from the second row.

The `<table body>` is a `<sep>`-separated list of *`M×N`* items (*`M`* and *`N`* are the number of items in the `<header row>` and `<first column>` lists) which will be added one by one to the table in row-major order (that is, the first *`M`* items are put in the first row, the next *`M`* items are put in the second row, and so on.

The table from your question can be typeset with (newlines added for clarity; spaces are trimmed around the items):

```latex
\cards{ lente | zomer | herfst | winter }
      { B | G | D | S }
      {3|1|6|1|
       2|2|3|2|
       4|3|4|3|
       5|7|5|4}
```

An example using the options:

```latex
\cards[sep = /, align = l]
  { foo / bar / baz }
  { F   / B   / B }
  {1/2/3/
   4/5/6/
   7/8/9}
```

Output:

> [image]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__forti_table_sep_tl
\tl_new:N \l__forti_table_align_tl
\tl_new:N \l__forti_table_temp_tl
\int_new:N \l__forti_table_ncols_int
\seq_new:N \g__forti_table_body_seq
\seq_new:N \g__forti_table_header_seq
\seq_new:N \g__forti_table_column_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gset_split:Nnn { Nx }
\keys_define:nn { forti }
  {
    , sep .tl_set:N = \l__forti_table_sep_tl
    , sep .initial:n = { | }
    , sep .value_required:n = true
    , align .tl_set:N = \l__forti_table_align_tl
    , align .initial:n = { c }
    , align .value_required:n = true
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \cards } { o m m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \IfValueT {#1} { \keys_set:nn { forti } {#1} }
      \forti_card_distribution:nnn {#2} {#3} {#4}
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \forti_card_distribution:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \__forti_seq_gset_split:Nn \g__forti_table_header_seq {#1}
    \__forti_seq_gset_split:Nn \g__forti_table_column_seq {#2}
    \__forti_seq_gset_split:Nn \g__forti_table_body_seq   {#3}
    \__forti_card_distribution_check_do:nnnN
      { \seq_count:N \g__forti_table_header_seq }
      { \seq_count:N \g__forti_table_column_seq }
      { \seq_count:N \g__forti_table_body_seq }
    \__forti_card_distribution:nn
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__forti_seq_gset_split:Nn #1 #2
  { \seq_gset_split:Nxn #1 { \tl_use:N \l__forti_table_sep_tl } {#2} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__forti_card_distribution_check_do:nnnN #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1*#2} = {#3}
      { #4 {#1} {#2} }
      {
        \msg_error:nnxx { forti } { wrong-number-of-items }
          { \int_eval:n {#1*#2} } {#3}
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__forti_card_distribution:nn #1 #2
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l__forti_table_ncols_int {#1}
    \use:x
      {
        \exp_not:N \begin{tabular}
          { * { \int_eval:n {#1 + 1} } { \tl_use:N \l__forti_table_align_tl } }
      }
      \toprule
        \c_alignment_token
        \seq_use:Nn \g__forti_table_header_seq { \c_alignment_token } \\
      \cmidrule { 2 - \int_eval:n {#1 + 1} }
        \int_step_function:nN { #2 }
          \__forti_typeset_table_row:n
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__forti_typeset_table_row:n #1
  {
    \seq_gpop:NN \g__forti_table_column_seq \l__forti_table_temp_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__forti_table_temp_tl
    \int_step_function:nN { \int_use:N \l__forti_table_ncols_int }
      \__forti_typeset_table_item:n
    \\
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__forti_typeset_table_item:n #1
  {
    \seq_gpop:NN \g__forti_table_body_seq \l__forti_table_temp_tl
    \use:x { \c_alignment_token \exp_not:V \l__forti_table_temp_tl }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { forti } { wrong-number-of-items }
  { Wrong~number~of~items~`#2'.~The~table~has~`#1'~cells. }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cards{ lente | zomer | herfst | winter }
      { B | G | D | S }
      {3|1|6|1|
       2|2|3|2|
       4|3|4|3|
       5|7|5|4}

\cards[sep = /, align = l]
  { foo / bar / baz }
  { F   / B   / B }
  {1/2/3/
   4/5/6/
   7/8/9}

\end{document}
```

And as requested, here's a version without the first column:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__forti_table_sep_tl
\tl_new:N \l__forti_table_align_tl
\tl_new:N \l__forti_table_temp_tl
\int_new:N \l__forti_table_ncols_int
\seq_new:N \g__forti_table_body_seq
\seq_new:N \g__forti_table_header_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gset_split:Nnn { Nx }
\keys_define:nn { forti }
  {
    , sep .tl_set:N = \l__forti_table_sep_tl
    , sep .initial:n = { | }
    , sep .value_required:n = true
    , align .tl_set:N = \l__forti_table_align_tl
    , align .initial:n = { c }
    , align .value_required:n = true
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \cards } { o m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \IfValueT {#1} { \keys_set:nn { forti } {#1} }
      \forti_card_distribution:nn {#2} {#3}
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \forti_card_distribution:nn #1 #2
  {
    \__forti_seq_gset_split:Nn \g__forti_table_header_seq {#1}
    \__forti_seq_gset_split:Nn \g__forti_table_body_seq   {#2}
    \__forti_card_distribution_check_do:nnN
      { \seq_count:N \g__forti_table_header_seq }
      { \seq_count:N \g__forti_table_body_seq }
    \__forti_card_distribution:nn
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__forti_seq_gset_split:Nn #1 #2
  { \seq_gset_split:Nxn #1 { \tl_use:N \l__forti_table_sep_tl } {#2} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__forti_card_distribution_check_do:nnN #1 #2 #3
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \int_mod:nn {#2}{#1} } = { 0 }
      { #3 {#1} {#2} }
      { \msg_error:nnxx { forti } { wrong-number-of-items } {#1} {#2} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__forti_card_distribution:nn #1 #2
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l__forti_table_ncols_int {#1}
    \use:x
      {
        \exp_not:N \begin{tabular}
          { * { \int_eval:n {#1} } { \tl_use:N \l__forti_table_align_tl } }
      }
      \toprule
        \seq_use:Nn \g__forti_table_header_seq { \c_alignment_token } \\
      \midrule
        \int_step_function:nN { #2/#1 }
          \__forti_typeset_table_row:n
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__forti_typeset_table_row:n #1
  {
    \int_step_function:nN { \l__forti_table_ncols_int }
      \__forti_typeset_table_item:n
    \\
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__forti_typeset_table_item:n #1
  {
    \seq_gpop:NN \g__forti_table_body_seq \l__forti_table_temp_tl
    \use:x
      {
        \int_compare:nNnT {#1} > { 1 } { \c_alignment_token }
        \exp_not:V \l__forti_table_temp_tl
      }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { forti } { wrong-number-of-items }
  { Wrong~number~of~items~`#2'.~The~table~has~`#1'~cells. }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cards{ lente | zomer | herfst | winter }
      {3|1|6|1|
       2|2|3|2|
       4|3|4|3|
       5|7|5|4}

\cards[sep = /, align = l]
  { foo / bar / baz }
  {1/2/3/
   4/5/6/
   7/8/9}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for your code. it work well. Can you create other without column (BGDS or F B B). Thanks

Comment: @latexforti Sure, I added a version which doesn't have a first column. Is that what you wanted? (Sorry for the delay; busy day :-)