# Replace \choice[1] with \CorrectChoice (hacking around a LyX limitation)

Tags: lyx, itemize, exam

I'm working on a *simple* layout in LyX 2.2 for the exam class. Many things work very well, especially with the `LatexType Item_Environment` style in LyX layouts. However, I'm stuck at how to deal with the multiple-choice environment, because

```
\choice
\CorrectChoice
```

are essentially two different `\item` possibilities within a `LatexType Item_Environment` (for LyX layouts). It doesn't look possible to have two different `ItemCommand` definitions in LyX. Arguably, `\CorrectChoice` is just a special case of `\choice`, but it's a lot to change the Exam class...

I realized it would be much easier if `\CorrectChoice` were just a `\choice` with an optional argument set to true (or 1), e.g., `\choice[1]`. Perhaps there's a way to hack it back to `\CorrectChoice` after LyX generates the LaTeX and before the LaTeX is compiled?

I have seen some hacking things done like this with the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf), but I couldn't find anything obvious. I admit I'm not much of a TeX hacker. It would be great to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out to be basic LaTeX hacking (rewriting a macro). Here's how I accomplished it, based on advice from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314/17868):

- In LyX, set the `ItemCommand` in the `Item_Environment` to `\mychoice`
- Add an optional argument for the items, as follows. Here's an example in the `exam.layout` file I'm developing:

  ```
  Style Multiple_Choice_Answers_(checkboxes)
    CopyStyle        Enumerate
    Category         Answers
    LatexType        Item_Environment
    LatexName        checkboxes
    ItemCommand      mychoice
    LabelType        Enumerate
    LabelSep         xx

    Argument item:1
      MenuString     "Mark correct"
      LabelString    "✓"
      Decoration     Classic
    EndArgument

  End
  ```

  In this case, multiple-choice answers (with checkboxes) have an optional "Mark correct" inset (that can contain anything). It will generate the `\mychoice[]` equivalent of an item.
- In the document preamble, there need to be some commands to rewrite `\mychoice` according to the presence of the optional parameter (indicating the correct choice). As pointed out in the comments, we should use the `Preamble` ... `EndPreamble` construct in the `.layout` file, as this keeps this change also with the layout. Also, the `makeat...` is best left to LyX to manage (one of the many reasons I adore LyX is it manages well the complexity of LaTeX).

  ```
  Preamble
      % hack to rewrite \mychoice or \mychoice[] to \choice or \CorrectChoice respectively
      \def\mychoice{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
      \def\@with[#1]{\CorrectChoice}
      \def\@without{\choice}
  EndPreamble
  ```

In LyX, the multiple choices look like this:
[image]

LyX generates this code:

```
\begin{checkboxes}
\mychoice Here's an answer
\mychoice Here's another
\mychoice[] This is the correct answer.
\mychoice This is not correct.
\end{checkboxes}
```

Here's the output in PDF (with answers shown):

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Note that the LyX preamble is already inside `\makeatletter…\makeatother` so by writing `\makeatother` in the preamble you might mess things up. Also you can use the `InPreamble` layout tag to move your preamble code to the layout. All together this would make a nice LyX module.

Comment: @G.M. I'm assuming you meant `Preamble` ... `PreambleEnd`? I'm making those changes (testing) and will update my answer. I'm going to put the layout on github.

Comment: You are right, `Preamble…PreambleEnd` as per Customization 5.3.6.