# How to pass optional arguments to command?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, arguments

I'm trying to write my own command that wraps the `\VerbatimInput` command. I'd like my command to take optional arguments (those given inside `[...]`) and pass those directly to `\VerbatimInput[...]`. Of course, if the optional arguments to my command are not given, then nothing should be passed to `\VerbatimInput`.

How can I do this? I'm a relative novice to creating custom commands in LaTeX.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument

Comment: This mostly depends on what “wrapping” you're doing. But I guess that `\newcommand{\foo}[2][]{...\VerbatimInput[#1]{#2}...}` should do.

Comment: Use New Renew and DeclareDocumentCommand as Christian Hupfer suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a macro argument is supposed to be a set of key-value pairs, making use of standard packages to the purpose (`keyval`, `xkeyval` and others), it is generally harmless to pass it the empty list.

So

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2][]{%
  <actions to be performed before>%
  \VerbatimInput[#1]{#2}%
  <actions to be performed after>%
}
```

is the method you're looking for, because `fancyvrb` *does* use `keyval`.

Answer (score 9):

egreg provided the easiest way with `\newcommand{\foo}[2][]{\VerbatimInput[#1]{#2}}`, here's the `xparse` way with `\NewDocumentCommand` and checking with `\IfValueTF{#1}` whether the optional (o) argument is given or not.

If more optional arguments are desired, it is definitely easier with `\NewDocumentCommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{filecontents}{helloworldexample.c}
 #include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{filecontents}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myverb}{om}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \VerbatimInput[{#1}]{#2}%
  }{%
    \VerbatimInput{#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\myverb{helloworldexample.c}

\myverb[frame=single,numbers=left]{helloworldexample.c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Generally, if a command accepts an optional argument consisting of a list of “key=value” items, it does not balk if it is passed an empty list.

Comment: @egreg: True. But this is on the safe side for other occasions, where there is no such key-value interface lurking behind the optional argument.

Comment: @egreg In the general case, the default value for the optional argument can be non-empty regardless whether the optional argument is intended for key-value pairs.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `[{#1}]` allows square brackets inside `#1`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thanks, I've added your suggestion.

Comment: I like this answer, but I used the simple method as provided by @egreg as you suggested. Is it kosher to accept an answer that wasn't used in the end?

Comment: @jlconlin: If it is a useful answer (an alternative) it is a 'must' to accept the answer ;-)