# One `\newcommand` for inserting figures differentiating two cases with/without captions

Tags: macros, floats, optional-arguments, arguments

I have written the following two `\newcommand` for inserting figures with or without a caption, respectively.

```
% for fig with caption: #1: width/size; #2: fig file; #3: fig caption
\newcommand{\figwithcaption}[3]{
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
      \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
      \caption{#3}
  \end{figure}
}

% for fig without caption: #1: width/size; #2: fig file
\newcommand{\fignocaption}[2]{
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \end{figure}
}
```

How to unify them into one `\newcommand` called, say, `\fig` which differentiates the two cases above according to the actual number of arguments it receives?

```
\fig{width = 0.50\textwidth}{fig/duck.pdf} % for fig without caption
\fig{width = 0.50\textwidth}{fig/duck.pdf}{A duck.} % for fig with caption
```

Comment: I would not recommend this as it makes the code very hard to read (better to make editor templates/shortcuts). But this can be done using the `xparse` package (it uses a different syntax), it can do optional arguments in `{}`'s (I think it is the `g` specifier), then you can test of `#3` has a value, and if it has add a caption.

Comment: @daleif I would  prefer `\NewDocumentCommand\fig{mmo}{..\includegraphics[{#1}]{#2}..\IfValueT{#3}{\caption{#3}}..}`. That way it still has the usual LaTeX way for optional arguments `\fig{..}{..}[optional caption]`.

Comment: @Manuel that would still work with the g modifier, and it is still safe as long as there is a space after the argument. But I still agree with David, users should not do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Really I wouldn't use a command at all, it is better to use the enviornment syntax (for example it helps editors to syntax highlight or give context sensitive help if you don't hide the standard syntax)

If you do use a command beware adding extra white space (your definitions add several space tokens).

That said, `\newcommand` supports defining commands with an optional argument.

```
\newcommand{\fig}[3][\relax]{%
  \begin{figure}[htp]%
    \centering
      \includegraphics[#2]{#3}%
      \ifx\relax#1\else\caption{#1}\fi
  \end{figure}%
}

\fig{width = 0.50\textwidth}{fig/duck.pdf} % for fig without caption
\fig[Zzzzz]{width = 0.50\textwidth}{fig/duck.pdf} % for fig without caption
```

Comment: I have to upvote, because your macro is identical to the one I was about to post, even down to the `\relax`.

Comment: Really great and simple answer. I had a similar need and implemented the method described in [that thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument). Are there any significant differences in efficiency? Would you say that your approach is "better"?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes sorry I couldn't squeeze stackengine in.

Comment: @Florian The newcommand version is easier to read so in human efficiency it wins. Possibly the lower level version takes a couple of expansions less, but  if you can time the difference you have a very slow computer or several million instances of this in the document. But as I say, I recommend doing neither.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you gain too much with this approach. Anyway, here's a possible implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hfig}{O{}mO{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { hengxin/fig } { #3 }
  \use:x { \exp_not:N \begin{figure}[\l_hengxin_hfig_pos_tl] }
  \centering
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_hengxin_hfig_caption_tl
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_hengxin_hfig_shortcaption_tl
     {
      \caption{\l_hengxin_hfig_caption_tl}
     }
     {
      \caption[\l_hengxin_hfig_shortcaption_tl]{\l_hengxin_hfig_caption_tl}
     }
   }
  \end{figure}
  \group_end:
 }
\keys_define:nn { hengxin/fig }
 {
  caption .tl_set:N = \l_hengxin_hfig_caption_tl,
  shortcaption .tl_set:N = \l_hengxin_hfig_shortcaption_tl,
  pos .tl_set:N = \l_hengxin_hfig_pos_tl,
  pos .initial:n = htp,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hfig[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\hfig[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}[
  caption=This is a caption\label{aaa},
  pos=bp
]

\end{document}
```

You can also specify a `shortcaption` key, for the case `\caption[Short]{Long}`.

[image]