# \IfNoValueTF - How to force "no value" if there (are brackets but there) is no value for an argument

Tags: latex3, xparse, optional-arguments, arguments

This code uses **LaTeX3**, the **xparse**-package and in particular the `\IfNoValueTF` command as explained in [Will Robertson's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2925/67761) to the OP "[Different command definitions with and without optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument)".

It sounds a little bit strange if you want to use a command called `\IfNoValueTF`, of which the name seems to suggest it checks for whether or not an argument contains any value, to have to ask a question to **force** a return as if the check resulted in a "non-value", in a case where in everyday language one would argue there is no non-empty-value in that argument indeed.

But, quite on the contrary ... `\IfNoValueTF` only seems to check whether or not there are any brackets. Please take a look at the self-explanatory MWE below, which checks whether or not a third argument is included.

Of course, quite possibly I have just misunderstood how to use either `\IfNoValueTF` or `\DeclareDocumentCommand \mainentry { m m o } {%`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \mainentry { m m o } {%
  \IfNoValueTF {#3} {%
\Large {\bfseries#1} \endgraf #2 \scriptsize NO \normalsize \vskip 1cm
  }{%
\Large {\bfseries#1} \endgraf #2 \endgraf #3 \scriptsize YES \normalsize \vskip 1cm
  }%
}

\begin{document}

A) There should be a YES here. OK.

\mainentry{
first
}{
second
}[
third
]

B) There should be a NO here. OK.

\mainentry{
first
}{
second
}

C) There should be a NO here. FAIL.

\mainentry{
first
}{
second
}[]

D) There should be a NO here. FAIL.

\mainentry{
first
}{
second
}[
]


E) There should be a NO here. FAIL.

\mainentry{
first
}{
second
}[
%
]

\end{document}
```

Comment: A missing argument is not the same as an empty argument or an argument with spaces. If you want to test for a blank argument (empty or only spaces), use `\ifblank` from etoolbox, or `\tl_if_blank:nTF` from expl3.

Comment: Thanks. If you could find some time, I would be interested in an answer. After your comment, I tried using `\tl_if_blank:nTF` but because I am so unexperienced I couldn't make it happen.

Comment: `\ExplSyntaxOn \NewDocumentCommand \mainentry { m m O{} } { .. \tl_if_blank:nTF { #3 } { NO } { YES } .. } \ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. @Manuel  Why did have to change `{ m m o }` into `{ m m O{} }` please?

Comment: `o` is something that works precisely for `\IfValue` tests. `O{}` is just an optional argument with default empty value (if you did `O{asdf}` then `asdf` would be the default value), and with that one you can have a correct `\tl_if_blank:` test (no optional = blank, optional but empty = blank, optional with something inside = not blank).

Comment: If you *require* a syntax such as `\mainentry{a}{b}[]`, then the final argument is not optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Ulrike Fischer's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394991/ifnovaluetf-how-to-force-no-value-if-there-are-brackets-but-there-is-no-v?noredirect=1#comment982162_394991), combined with [Manuel's first comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21930/manuel):

One has to change the lines

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \mainentry { m m o } {%
  \IfNoValueTF {#3} {%
```

into

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \mainentry { m m O{} } {%
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #3 } {%
```

[Manuel's second comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394991/ifnovaluetf-how-to-force-no-value-if-there-are-brackets-but-there-is-no-v?noredirect=1#comment982189_394991) explained that for `O{}` is just an optional argument with a default empty value.

This works both for blank arguments, arguments with spaces or even arguments of which there are no brackets present.

Comment: Or create an `\IfEmptyTF` command: `\ExplSyntaxOn  \cs_set_eq:NN  \IfEmptyTF  \tl_if_blank:nTF  \ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: Using multiple comments from various people and gluing an answer together is not really kosher, one should rather ask the users to provide an answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK. I just thought they didn't want to, as they already answered in the comments ... Users with a very high score have asked me to provide the answer myself before ... I guess they sometimes might be too busy to want to do it themselves.