# Different command definitions with more than one optional arguments arguments

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I was reading the following post [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument) on how to implement Different command definitions with and without optional argument. The example mentioned in this link covers the case of one optional argument. Following the same guidelines, I have been trying to do the same with two optional arguments using the following code without any luck:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{myDummy}
{

\def\myDummy
{
    \@ifnextchar[
    {\@WithAtLeastParam}{\@WithoutParam}
}
\def\@WithoutParam#1{x_{#1}}
\def\@WithAtLeastParam[#1]
{
    \@ifnextchar[
    {\@WithTwoParam}{\@WithOneParam}
}
\def\@WithTwoParam#1[#2]#3{x_{#1\rightarrow #2,#3}}

\def\@WithOneParam#1#2{x_{#1\rightarrow #2}}
}
\makeatother
```

Could any one please tell me what I have been doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I have removed the LaTeX3 tag since your code example does not use LaTeX3. If you are interested in a LaTeX3/`xparse` solution, you may want to look into https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2925/35864

Comment: BTW: This code could cause unwanted white space because the line ends are not commented with `%` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864). If it is a math command, the spaces may not be problematic, but it is a good idea to keep this in mind in case one decides to write text mode macros.

Comment: Note quite in this case, but the general idea is correct. `\def\@WithoutParam#1{x_{#1}}` does not end in a control sequence name that would gobble the space. And it actually has a space after it, but that is irrelevant because it is used in the preamble. If used in the document that becomes apparent, have a look at https://gist.github.com/moewew/bf2c7bda7be3a0bc1c189bde61916b26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to comment out the newline after `\def\@WithAtLeastParam[#1]`, else the argument must be followed by a space and TeX will fail to parse the macro arguments if there is no space. This is not necessary for `\def\myDummy` because of TeX's rules for spaces following control sequences, but behind each `\def` which's line ends with something that is not a control sequence the line ending should be commented. I also commented each parasitic space which could sneak into the macro (though those won't matter as the macro is used in math mode).

Also `\@WithAtLeastParam` grabs the first parameter, which is why you have to forward the grabbed argument to both `\@WithTwoParam` and `\@WithOneParam`.

I removed the `\@ifundefined` test for simplicity, you might add it again.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\myDummy%
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[
      {\@WithAtLeastParam}
      {\@WithoutParam}%
  }
\def\@WithoutParam#1{x_{#1}}
\def\@WithAtLeastParam[#1]%
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[
      {\@WithTwoParam{#1}}
      {\@WithOneParam{#1}}%
  }
\def\@WithTwoParam#1[#2]#3%
  {%
    x_{#1\rightarrow #2,#3}%
  }
\def\@WithOneParam#1#2%
  {%
    x_{#1\rightarrow #2}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\myDummy{1} \myDummy[1]{2} \myDummy[1][2]{3}$
\end{document}
```

The same behaviour but implemented using `xparse`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand \myDummy { o o m }
  {%
    x_{\IfValueT{#1}{#1\rightarrow}\IfValueT{#2}{#2,}#3}%
  }

\begin{document}
$\myDummy{1} \myDummy[1]{2} \myDummy[1][2]{3}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this issue. So there reason`\def\@WithoutParam#1{x_{#1}}` is not required to ended in a % is because it ends with a control sequence, where as `\def\@WithAtLeastParam[#1]%` needs the % because it doesn't end with a control sequence?

Comment: @YasharZ no, `\def\@WithoutParam#1{x_{#1}}` doesn't need the trailing `%`, because the argument of `\def` ends with the last closing bracket and since it is used before `\begin{document}` there is no whitespace inserted. `\def\@WithAtLeastParam[#1]%` needs the `%`, because the argument of `\def` which is specifying the arguments available to the defined macro (`\@WithAtLeastParam`) begins after the marco's name and ends at the opening `{`. This would contain a space prior to `{`, so the macro's arguments would be defined as `[#1] ` where a space must follow the closing `]`.