# How to define a command with two optional arguments?

Tags: macros, xparse, optional-arguments

I would like to have a single command that can take either 1, 2, or 3 arguments and do something different for each number of arguments.

```
\c{a}       -> C_a
\c{a}{b}    -> C_{a}^{[b]}
\c{a}{b}{c} -> C_{a,c}^{[b]}
```

Since Latex has no command overloading, I decided that optional arguments are good enough:

```
\c{a}       -> C_a
\c[b]{a}    -> C_{a}^{[b]}
\c[c][b]{a} -> C_{a,c}^{[b]}
```

I found that [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2925/17444) using `xparse` might do exactly what I need. However his answer works only for 2 optional arguments. He mentions how to extend it to any number of arguments, but I couldn't figure it out. I tried:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
....
\DeclareDocumentCommand \c { o o m } {%
  \IfNoValueTF {#1} {%
    \IfNoValueTF {#2} {%
      C_{#3}%
     }{%
      C_{#3}^{[#2]}%
  }%
  }{%
    C_{#2, #3}^{[#1]}%
  }% 
}

$\c{a} \c[b]{a} \c[c][b]{a}$
```

But it seems that I cannot get the branch with two arguments to work:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In LaTeX you don't need braces with undelimited single-token-arguments. Thus: How to handle `\c{a}bc`? Shall this mean `\c` has one arg and the one-arg-call to `\c` is trailed by letters `b` and `c` which do not form args of `\c`?  Shall this mean a three-argument-call to `\c` with two args just not being nested in braces as braces are not really needed with single-token-arguments?  You can check if a single-argument-macro's arg in turn consists of three or two or one brace-delimited arguments, i.e.,  `\c{{a}{b}{c}}`, but then you need to specify behavior for other cases and spaces as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should start from examining `#2` rather than `#1`, because `#2` only can have a value if `#1` has, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \C { o o m } {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {%
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
     {%
      C_{#3}%
     }
     {%
      C_{#3}^{[#1]}%
     }%
   }
   {%
    C_{#3, #1}^{[#2]}%
   }% 
}

\begin{document}

$\C{a} \quad \C[b]{a} \quad \C[c][b]{a}$ 

\end{document}
```

And *don't* use `\DeclareDocumentCommand` to override the meaning of `\c`: you'll regret it when you have to cite some French or Turkish author with “ç” in their name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You wish to define a macro `\c`. But `\c` is already defined in LaTeX.
Therefore I will henceforth not refer to the macro in question as `\c`.
Instead I will refer to the macro in question as `\macroc`.

---

Are you aware that in TeX/LaTeX undelimited arguments consisting of a single token don't need to be nested in braces?

After defining `\newcommand\foo[1]{This is argument 1: #1.}`,
`\foo{b}` will yield the same result as
`\foo b`.

After defining `\newcommand\bar[2]{This is argument 1: #1. This is argument 2: #2.}`, the following calls will all yield the same result:
`\bar{a}{b}`
`\bar a{b}`
`\bar {a}b`
`\bar ab`
`\bar{a} {b}`
`\bar a {b}`
`\bar {a} b`
`\bar a b`

This is because

1. you don't need braces when undelimited arguments consist of a single token.
2. (La)TeX does discard space tokens preceding undelimited arguments.

When called as  `\macroc{a}{b}c`—how shall `\macroc` "know" whether the user intends to have `c` as `\macroc`'s third argument which consists of the single token `c` or whether the user intends to have `\macroc` called with only two arguments, namely `{a}` and `{b}` while `c` shall not be considered a third argument?

The situation is ambiguous.

You can turn the situation into something unambiguous by having `\macroc` process only one undelimited argument and having `\macroc` check whether that argument in turn is of one of the patterns

`{⟨argument 1⟩}`

`{⟨argument 1⟩}{⟨argument 2⟩}`

`{⟨argument 1⟩}{⟨argument 2⟩}{⟨argument 3⟩}`

and having `\macroc` act accordingly in case one of these patterns is detected and having `\macroc` deliver an error-message otherwise.

I.e.,

`\macroc{{⟨argument 1⟩}}`

`\macroc{{⟨argument 1⟩}{⟨argument 2⟩}}`

`\macroc{{⟨argument 1⟩}{⟨argument 2⟩}{⟨argument 3⟩}}`

---

With the example below, `\macroc` does process one undelimited argument.

Syntax: `\macroc{⟨argument⟩}`.

In case `⟨argument⟩` is of pattern `{⟨argument 1⟩}`,
`\macrocatonearg{⟨argument 1⟩}` will be carried out.

In case `⟨argument⟩` is of pattern `{⟨argument 1⟩}{⟨argument 2⟩}`, 
`\macrocattwoargs{⟨argument 1⟩}{⟨argument 2⟩}` will be carried out.

In case `⟨argument⟩` is of pattern `{⟨argument 1⟩}{⟨argument 2⟩}{⟨argument 3⟩}`, 
`\macrocatthreeargs{⟨argument 1⟩}{⟨argument 2⟩}{⟨argument 3⟩}` will be carried out.

In all other cases an error-message will inform the user about a syntax-error.

Thus you can do, e.g., :

`\macroc{{a}}`

`\macroc{{a}{b}}`

`\macroc{{a}{b}{c}}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,
%%    \UD@gobble, \UD@gobbletwo, \UD@gobblethree
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherBrace,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@gobble[1]{}%
\newcommand\UD@gobbletwo[2]{}%
\newcommand\UD@gobblethree[3]{}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has no leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@firstoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% \macroc for processing one argument within which
%%  you may have one or two or three brace-nested arguments:
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\macrocatonearg[1]{C_#1}%
\newcommand\macrocattwoargs[2]{C_{#1}^{[#2]}}%
\newcommand\macrocatthreeargs[3]{C_{#1,#3}^{[#2]}}%
\newcommand\macrocatsyntaxerror{%
  \@latex@error{Incorrect Syntax}{Specify either one or two or three arguments that are nested in braces.}%
}%
\newcommand\macroc[1]{%
   \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{%
      \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobble#1}{%
         \macrocatonearg#1%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherBrace\expandafter{\UD@gobble#1}{%
          \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletwo#1}{%
            \macrocattwoargs#1%
          }{%
            \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherBrace\expandafter{\UD@gobbletwo#1}{%
               \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobblethree#1}{%
                 \macrocatthreeargs#1%
               }{\macrocatsyntaxerror}%
            }{\macrocatsyntaxerror}%
          }%
        }{\macrocatsyntaxerror}%
      }%
   }{\macrocatsyntaxerror}%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\verb|$\macroc{{a}}$|: $\macroc{{a}}$ \bigskip

\verb|$\macroc{{a}{b}}$|: $\macroc{{a}{b}}$ \bigskip

\verb|$\macroc{{a}{b}{c}}$|: $\macroc{{a}{b}{c}}$ \bigskip

% Syntax-errors:
% 
% $\macroc{{a}{b}{c}{d}}$
%
% $\macroc{ {a}}$
% 
% $\macroc{{a} {b}}$
%
% $\macroc{a}$
%
% $\macroc{}$

\end{document}
```

[image]