# Mysterious horizontal space when using conditional macro

Tags: spacing, macros, conditionals, optional-arguments

In order to deal with both burdensome expressions `$K$-vector space` and `$K$-vector space $E$` at once, and this in both text and math mode alike, I defined a fine working shortcut taking two arguments, the second of them optional, as follows:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vs}[2]{%
    \relax\ifmmode
        \ifx\relax#2\relax
            #1\text{-vector space}%
        \else
            #1\text{-vector space }#2%
        \fi
    \else
        \ifx\relax#2\relax
            $#1$-vector space%
        \else
            $#1$-vector space $#2$%
        \fi
    \fi}
\makeatother
```

Thanks to the nice macro `\ifemptyarg` created by `egreg` in [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58638/7012), I could redefine `\vs` in a thriftier way:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\ifemptyarg#1{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax    % H. Oberdiek
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
    \fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\vs}[2]{%
    \relax\ifmmode
        \ifemptyarg{#2}
            {#1\text{-vector space}}
            {#1\text{-vector space }#2}
    \else
    \ifemptyarg{#2}
        {$#1$-vector space}
        {$#1$-vector space $#2$}
    \fi}


\begin{document}

For any field $K$, a consequence of the Axiom of Choice
is that there is a basis for every \vs{K}{E}, but less known
is the fact that if there is a basis for every \vs{K}{},
and this for any $K$, then the Axiom of Choice holds!

\end{document}
```

But mysteriously, with this version of `\vs` the result of both `[...] \vs{K}{E},` and `[...] \vs{K}{},` is the same as if instead I was respectively writing `[...] $K$-vector space\ ,` and `[...] $K$-vector space $E$\ ,`, namely, with an undesired extra space after each comma. Why?

Comment: `$K$-vector space\ .` is obviously wrong, the space should go away.

Comment: @Fitzcarraldo Welcome to TeX.SE! As an alernative to the artisanal `\ifemptyarg` command (good craftwork, though ;-), you could use `\ifstrempty` or `\ifblank` from the [etoolbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

Comment: @egreg I couldn't agree more with you, but that's what my code was doing, that is, as if I had exactly written `$K$-vector space\ .`. Hope that my new wording is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several spaces inserted by newlines...

```latex
\newcommand{\vs}[2]{%
    \relax\ifmmode
        \ifemptyarg{#2}%
            {#1\text{-vector space}}%
            {#1\text{-vector space }#2}%
    \else
    \ifemptyarg{#2}%
        {$#1$-vector space}%
        {$#1$-vector space $#2$}%
\fi}
```

works. Notice that the "%" after the `\ifemptyarg{#2}` is not necessary, but well...

Comment: Technically you only need the ending `%` in `\ifemptyarg{.}{..}{...}`.