# Modify the attributes of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

**Question:**

How can I modify the following code so that it takes 2 more arguments (background color, and font color)?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}


\begin{document}
    
\circled{+}
    
\end{document}
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Ideal Output:**

`\circled{+}{#00d131}{#ffffff}` would yield:

[image]

**FWIW:**

I'm open to other suggestions if the above MWE is not the optimum method for such tasks.

Comment: The code you gave is not an MWE. See here how to produce one: [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: @AndréC How is it now?

Comment: It's perfect now !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, and more details please read [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument) and [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros) for how to define a command with and without optional arguments.

```
\newcommand*\circled[3]{
    \definecolor{fill_color}{HTML}{#2}
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle, fill=fill_color, draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {\textcolor[HTML]{#3}{#1}};}}

\circled{+}{00d131}{ffff3f}
```